# Pop first element of array instead of last (reversed array_pop)?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a PHP function that would 'pop' first element of array? 
`array_pop()` pops last element, but I'd like to pop the first.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You are looking for array_shift().

[PHP Array Shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Answer (score 38):

**Quick Cheatsheet** If you are not familiar with the lingo, here is a quick translation of alternate terms, which may be easier to remember:

```
* array_unshift()  -  (aka Prepend ;; InsertBefore ;; InsertAtBegin )     
* array_shift()    -  (aka UnPrepend ;; RemoveBefore  ;; RemoveFromBegin )

* array_push()     -  (aka Append ;; InsertAfter ;; InsertAtEnd )     
* array_pop()      -  (aka UnAppend ;; RemoveAfter ;; RemoveFromEnd )
```

Answer (score 3):

While `array_shift()` is definitely the answer to your question, it's worth mentioning that it can be an unnecessarily slow process when working with large arrays. (or many iterations)

After retrieving the first element, `array_shift()` re-indexes all numerical keys in an array, so that the element that used to be at `[1]` becomes `[0]` and an element at `[10000]` becomes `[9999]`.

The larger the array, the more keys to re-index. And if you're iterating over large arrays, calling `array_shift` on multiple iterations, the performance hit can rack up.

Benchmarks show for large arrays it's often cheaper to reverse the array order and pop the elements from the end.

```
    $array = array_reverse($array);
    $value = array_pop($array);
```

`array_pop()` obviously doesn't need to re-index since it's taking from the end, and `array_reverse()` returns a new array by simply copying the array passed to it, from back to front. `array_reverse($array, true)` can be used to preserve `key => value` pairs where needed.

[EDIT] I should mention, the downside to the reverse-pop method is memory consumption, where `array_reverse()` generates a new array, while `array_shift()` works in place. Thus takes longer.

Comment: Is array_reverse() really faster than array_shift()? Array_reverse() still has to do a pass on every element during the copy. Where is the savings? And with the added memory consumption, wouldn't array_reverse() be slower than array_shift()? Did you benchmark? Also, I don't know how PHP calculates array indexing, but I assume they are not linked lists (maybe they are?). An array is a pointer to a memory block. Therefore, PHP could be implemented to free the first array element and point the array to the second element's memory address. I do not know how PHP actually implements arrays though.

Comment: @BlueWater Here's a link to someone else's benchmark results. http://www.evardsson.com/blog/2010/02/05/comparing-php-array_shift-to-array_pop/
It's been ages since I even thought about PHP, but you got me thinking again. Is it that flipping the head and tail values are all that's necessary in a reverse? I'm honestly not sure what array_reverse() is doing internally. But its not re-indexing the array it returns. Maybe you can tell me!

I think you'd enjoy this article, if you haven't seen it: https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. The benchmark link tests multiple passes over the array.  But nowhere on this page is multiple passes mentioned.  I thought you were talking about a single pop.  Certainly for multiple pops, a single reverse will yield linear time, whereas shift will yield n^m time, where m is the number of pops.

Answer (score 2):

For me array_slice() works fine,
Say:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
//array_slice($array,offset); where $array is the array to be sliced, and   offset is the number of array elements to be sliced
$arr2 = array_slice($arr,3);//or
$arr2 = array_slice($arr,-3);//or
$arr2 = array_slice($arr,-3,3);//return 4,5 and 6 in a new array
$arr2 = array_slice($arr,0,4);//returns 1,2,3 and 4 in a new array
```

Comment: why not just array_shift() it's so much more effective?

Answer (score 0):

Use `key()` and `unset()`.

When array's keys is **Numeric**, `array_shift()` change array keys to started from 0.

```php
$arr = [5 => 5, 71 => 71, 1 => 1, 8 => 8];
$first_key = key($arr);
$first_element = $arr[$first_key];  //       <-- get first element of array
echo $first_element;  // print '5'
unset($arr[$first_key]);  //                           <-- delete first element of array
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52826684/2943403