# How to delete an array element based on key?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete an element from an array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php)

For instance,

```
Array(      
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => open
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => good
            [1] => center
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => close
        )
)
```

I want to delete the element which key is *1*, after the operation:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => open
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => close
        )
)
```

Comment: The answers for this question seem to answer "How do I delete elements from an array using an _index_ and not a _key_.

Comment: @LucasMorgan actually there's no difference, the index is the key for those without an explicit index.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

PHP

```
unset($array[1]);
```

Answer (score 34):

You don't say what language you're using, but looking at that output, it looks like PHP output (from `print_r()`).

If so, just use [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
unset($arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 22):

this looks like PHP to me. I'll delete if it's some other language.

Simply `unset($arr[1]);`