# Unset array by key and value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, unset

My array are $arrIncome and $arrExpense. They have some the same date and some not the same date.

```
$arrIncome = [
   [
     'date' => '01-01-2019',
     'total' => '500',
   ],
   [
     'date' => '02-01-2019',
     'total' => '200',
   ],
   [
     'date' => '03-01-2019',
     'total' => '300',
   ],
   [
     'date' => '04-01-2019',
     'total' => '900',
   ],
];

$arrExpense= [
   [
     'date' => '01-01-2019',
     'total' => '50',
   ],
   [
     'date' => '02-01-2019',
     'total' => '60',
   ],
   [
     'date' => '07-01-2019',
     'total' => '25',
   ],
   [
     'date' => '08-01-2019',
     'total' => '50',
   ],
];
```

I loop in $arrIncome array, if I found income date have in $arrExpense array, I will remove an array in $arrExpense by income date of $arrIncome, because I want to make unique date.

```
foreach ($arrIncome as $income){
        $isExistExpense = array_filter($arrExpense, function($expense) use($income){
            return $expense->date == date('Y-m-d', strtotime($income->date));
        });


        if(count($isExistExpense) > 0 ){
            foreach ($isExistExpense as $expense){
                // THIS PLACE TO UNSET $arrExpense by date value
                unset($arrExpense['date'] = $income->date); // this is a wrong way
            }
        }else{
            // my code more here.....
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to unset array by key and value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an array element based on key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672156/how-to-delete-an-array-element-based-on-key)

Comment: I think it doesn't the same what i want. Array doesn't the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must unset it by the index.

You can do it like:

```
// Get the intersection of the dates 
$isExistExpense = array_intersect(
    array_column($arrIncome,'date'), 
    array_column($arrExpense,'date'));
// Loop through the `$arrExpense` and unset the that exist in the array. 
foreach($arrExpense as $index=>$vals){
    if(in_array($vals['date'], $isExistExpense)){
        unset($arrExpense[$index]);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: It's weird. You have a typo (`$v` should be `$vals`) but the code works anyway...

Comment: Updated. That is weird.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, the code wasn't working with `$v` it was just that I was testing it on my pre-filtered version of `$arrExpense` so it wasn't actually doing anything (`$isExistExpense` was empty).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to directly remove the elements of `$arrExpense` that have dates which exist in `$arrIncome` (using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the list of dates in that array):

```
$arrExpense = array_filter($arrExpense, function ($v) use ($arrIncome) { 
    return !in_array($v['date'], array_column($arrIncome, 'date'));
});
print_r($arrExpense);
```

Output:

```
Array (
   [2] => Array ( [date] => 07-01-2019 [total] => 25 )
   [3] => Array ( [date] => 08-01-2019 [total] => 50 )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2Gvg0)

Comment: Yeah, that's better

Comment: Your answer is not remove array, but you just show different array on $arrExpense.

Comment: Your answer is not remove array, but you just show different array on $arrExpense.

Comment: @MengsengOeng the end result is the same, so does it matter?

Comment: Because I will to do more in $arrExpense. I must remove element of $arrExpense. Thank for answer.