# How do you remove an array element in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to loop through an array with `foreach` to check if a value exists. If the value does exist, I want to delete the element which contains it.

I have the following code:

```
foreach($display_related_tags as $tag_name) {
    if($tag_name == $found_tag['name']) {
        // Delete element
    }
}
```

I don't know how to delete the element once the value is found. How do I delete it?

I have to use `foreach` for this problem. There are probably alternatives to `foreach`, and you are welcome to share them.

Comment: This question is missing its [mcve].  It does not make a great canonical reference and answerers are afforded the freedom to stretch the interpretation of the input data to diversify recommended solutions -- not great for the researcher experience.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

If you also get the key, you can delete that item like this:

```
foreach ($display_related_tags as $key => $tag_name) {
    if($tag_name == $found_tag['name']) {
        unset($display_related_tags[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some additional info about optimizing by using `$key => &$tag_name` http://stackoverflow.com/a/2008893/922522

Comment: Note that indexed arrays with items unset may be represented as objects instead of arrays after a `json_encode()`. You can solve this with `$display_related_tags = array_values ($display_related_tags);` after the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Note that's the trick here is to add a value to the foreach loop ;-)

Comment: Please see @Neils answer. You will encounter unexpected bugs, especially if you work with Array of stdClasses. Do you like unexpected behavior? Me not.

Comment: @happy_marmoset Neils answer is not helping. Snippet `$projects =
                array_filter($projects, function ($project) {
                    return count($project->roles) > 0;
                });` it converts result into object.

Comment: **Important** If you are interested in keeping the array as ordered array, you need to call `display_related_tags = array_values(display_related_tags);` after it.

Answer (score 48):

A better solution is to use the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function:

```
$display_related_tags =
    array_filter($display_related_tags, function($e) use($found_tag){
        return $e != $found_tag['name'];
    });
```

As the php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) reads:

> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer in PHP 5, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.
>
> In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer.

Comment: Note that the 3rd parameter should be ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY in order to pass the key as $e here.

Comment: @namezero OK why does that matter here?

Comment: @AbraCadaver  From the documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php): 
   `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY - pass key as the only argument to callback instead of the value
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH - pass both value and key as arguments to callback instead of the value` 
`Default is 0 which will pass value as the only argument to callback instead. ` That said, reading the answer again in this case of course it would not matter as you claim.

Comment: **Important** If you are interested in keeping the array as ordered array, you need to call `display_related_tags = array_values(display_related_tags);` after it.

Comment: So, can we now say that it is safe, in PHP 7, to directly unset the item from the array? It definitely seems much leaner than using the `array_filter`, at least from the coder's perspective (I'm not sure about the actual implementation in the background).

Answer (score 12):

```
foreach($display_related_tags as $key => $tag_name)
{
    if($tag_name == $found_tag['name'])
        unset($display_related_tags[$key];
}
```

Comment: 'unlink' unlinks files, it has nothing to do with variables or, more specifically, arrays. Perhaps you mean 'unset'?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of doing foreach() loop on the array, it would be faster to use array_search() to find the proper key. On small arrays, I would go with foreach for better readibility, but for bigger arrays, or often executed code, this should be a bit more optimal:

```
$result=array_search($unwantedValue,$array,true);
if($result !== false) {
  unset($array[$result]);   
}
```

The strict comparsion operator !== is needed, because array_search() can return 0 as the index of the $unwantedValue.

Also, the above example will remove just the first value $unwantedValue, if the $unwantedValue can occur more then once in the $array, You should use array_keys(), to find all of them:

```
$result=array_keys($array,$unwantedValue,true)
foreach($result as $key) {
  unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php for more information.

Answer (score 0):

if you have scenario in which you have to remove more then one values from the foreach array in this case you have to pass value by reference in for each:
I try to explain this scenario:

```
foreach ($manSkuQty as $man_sku => &$man_qty) {

               foreach ($manufacturerSkus as $key1 => $val1) {

  // some processing here and unset first loops entries                     
 //  here dont include again for next iterations
                           if(some condition)
                            unset($manSkuQty[$key1]);

                        }
               }
}
```

in second loop you want to unset first loops entries dont come again in the iteration for performance purpose or else then unset from memory as well because in memory they present and will come in iterations.

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers which are giving light on how to unset. Rather than repeating code in all your classes make function like below and use it in code whenever required. In business logic, sometimes you don't want to expose some properties. Please see below one liner call to remove

```
public static function removeKeysFromAssociativeArray($associativeArray, $keysToUnset)
{
    if (empty($associativeArray) || empty($keysToUnset))
        return array();

    foreach ($associativeArray as $key => $arr) {
        if (!is_array($arr)) {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($keysToUnset as $keyToUnset) {
            if (array_key_exists($keyToUnset, $arr)) {
                unset($arr[$keyToUnset]);
            }
        }
        $associativeArray[$key] = $arr;
    }
    return $associativeArray;
}
```

Call like:

```
removeKeysFromAssociativeArray($arrValues, $keysToRemove);
```

Comment: I never call `empty()` on variables that are guaranteed to be declared.