# Unsetting array values in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, unset

I have a foreach loop set up to go through my array, check for a certain link, and if it finds it removes that link from the array.

My code:

```
foreach($images as $image)
{
    if($image == 'http://i27.tinypic.com/29yk345.gif' ||
    $image == 'http://img3.abload.de/img/10nx2340fhco.gif' ||
    $image == 'http://i42.tinypic.com/9pp2456x.gif')
    {
        unset($images[$image]);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't remove the array entires. It's probably something to do with `$images[$image]`, as that's not the key of the array entry, only the content? Is there a way to do this without incorporating a counter?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Thanks guys, but now I have another problem where the array entries don't actually get deleted.

My new code:

```
foreach($images[1] as $key => $image)
{
    if($image == 'http://i27.tinypic.com/29yk345.gif')
    $image == 'http://img3.abload.de/img/10nx2340fhco.gif' ||
    $image == 'http://i42.tinypic.com/9pp2456x.gif')
    {
        unset($images[$key]);
    }
}
```

$images is actuallty a two-dimensional array now hence why I need $images[1]. I have checked and it successfully goes around the array elements, and some elements do actually have some of those URLs in that I wish to delete, but they're not getting deleted. This is my `$images` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => useless
            [1] => useless
            [2] => useless
            [3] => useless
            [4] => useless
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://i27.tinypic.com/29yk345.gif
            [1] => http://img3.abload.de/img/10nx2340fhco.gif
            [2] => http://img3.abload.de/img/10nx2340fhco.gif
            [3] => http://i42.tinypic.com/9pp2456x.gif
        )

)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would also suggest if(in_array($image, array('http://i27.tinypic.com/29yk345.gif', 'http://img3.abload.de/img/10nx2340fhco.gif', 'http://i42.tinypic.com/9pp2456x.gif')). Makes it more readable ;)

Comment: Since you changed the array you're iterating, that needs to be reflected in your call to unset - unset($images[1][$key]);

Comment: And the parenthesis in the if statement are wrong but I guess this just typo (otherwise you would get an error message)

Comment: "Note:

When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. This means that you do not need to call reset() before a foreach loop.

As foreach relies on the internal array pointer changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior." Taken from the php manual

Answer (score 95):

```
foreach($images as $key => $image)
{
    if(in_array($image, array(
       'http://i27.tinypic.com/29ykt1f.gif',
       'http://img3.abload.de/img/10nxjl0fhco.gif',
       'http://i42.tinypic.com/9pp2tx.gif',
    ))
    {
        unset($images[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm having trouble actually deleting some of the array elements. See the edit in the first post :)

Comment: Then try `unset($images[1][$key]);`

Answer (score 78):

Try that:

```
foreach ($images[1] as $key => &$image) {
    if (yourConditionGoesHere) {
        unset($images[1][$key])
    }
}
unset($image); // detach reference after loop
```

Normally, `foreach` operates on a copy of your array so any changes you make, are made to that copy and don't affect the actual array.

So you need to unset the values via `$images[$key]`;

The reference on `&$image` prevents the loop from creating a copy of the array which would waste memory.

Comment: Thanks. I think what you're saying is related to my problem (see edit). Even if I add a `&` though it still doesn't work.

Comment: "The reference on &$image prevents the loop from creating a copy of the array which would waste memory." <- what I was looking for :)

Comment: After the loop you should `unset($image);`.

Comment: using & actually waste memory, for complete explanation, please read : https://flyleafbd.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/the-truth-about-php-variables/

Comment: @bruno are you sure that this is the case with PHP 7? The article is from 2011 and it mentions the ancient PHP 4

Comment: @lanDess you're rigth, i didn"t know that php7 has moved away from zval, but it seem to still be valid, please read :
https://schlueters.de/blog/archives/180-References-Still-bad-in-PHP-7.html

(ok, one source is not sufficient, so let's keep a doubt in mind)

Comment: @lanDess I found another source : 
https://nikic.github.io/2015/05/05/Internal-value-representation-in-PHP-7-part-1.html
section "References" => so, OK, in PHP7, this probleme is solved and using reference isn't a performance issue

Comment: Indeed the reference is not necessary. Arrays are always passed by reference until they are modified

Comment: @Ja͢ck Why do we need `After the loop you should unset($image);` ?

Comment: @IbrahimShendy safety, in case you reuse that variable later; if not, it would modify the last element of the array

Answer (score 13):

To answer the initial question (after your edit), you need to unset($images[1][$key]);

Now some more infos how PHP works:
You can safely unset elements of the array in foreach loop, and it doesn't matter if you have & or not for the array item. See this code:

```
$a=[1,2,3,4,5];
foreach($a as $key=>$val)
{
   if ($key==3) unset($a[$key]);
}
print_r($a);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [4] => 5
)
```

So as you can see, if you unset correct thing within the foreach loop, everything works fine.

Comment: you meant $key==4?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the index of the array element to remove it from the array, the next time you use the `$list` variable, you will see that the array is changed.

Try something like this

```
foreach($list as $itemIndex => &$item) {

   if($item['status'] === false) {
      unset($list[$itemIndex]);
   }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, see below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2008893/922522

Comment: See this method fail here: http://ideone.com/Vv4DR8

Comment: @Justin that's because you are unsetting $item instead of the item from the list. I forked your code, and this works: http://ideone.com/SY0XC3

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for solving that @rolandow!

Comment: Don't forget to use `unset($item)` after the foreach loop.

Answer (score 4):

`$image` is in your case the value of the item and not the key. Use the following syntax to get the key too:

```
foreach ($images as $key => $value) {
    /* … */
}
```

Now you can delete the item with `unset($images[$key])`.

Comment: This might work, but it will still copy the whole array to execute the foreach loop. So it's a waste of memory.
If I'm not mistaken, the approach with references (see my answer) is also faster than resolving the key/value pair each time the unset happens.

Comment: The second part is actually not so true. Sorry. Unsetting by reference does of course not work.

Comment: @Techpriester: `foreach` does always work on an internal copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($images as $key=>$image)                                
{               
   if($image == 'http://i27.tinypic.com/29ykt1f.gif' ||    
   $image == 'http://img3.abload.de/img/10nxjl0fhco.gif' ||    
   $image == 'http://i42.tinypic.com/9pp2tx.gif')     
   { unset($images[$key]); }                               
}
```

!!foreach($images as $key=>$image

cause $image is the value, so $images[$image] make no sense.

Comment: Fail. You should use `code sample` - not `blockquote`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the key of your items to remove them -- you can both the keys and the values, when looping using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

For instance :

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => 123,
    'b' => 456,
    'c' => 789, 
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
    if ($item == 456) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Will give you this array, in the end :

```
array
  'a' => int 123
  'c' => int 789
```

Which means that, in your case, something like this should do the trick :

```
foreach($images as $key => $image)
{
    if($image == 'http://i27.tinypic.com/29yk345.gif' ||
    $image == 'http://img3.abload.de/img/10nx2340fhco.gif' ||
    $image == 'http://i42.tinypic.com/9pp2456x.gif')
    {
        unset($images[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would also need a

```
$i--;
```

after each unset to not skip an element/

Because when you unset `$item[45]`, the next element in the for-loop should be `$item[45]` -  which was `[46]` before unsetting. If you would not do this, you'd always skip an element after unsetting.

Comment: But unset() will not change the array index so I don't think this $i-- is needed here. If the method array_splice() was used, then the elements would be shifted to cover the deleted hole and $i-- is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, I recently had the same problem with PHP and found out that when working with arrays that do not use `$key => $value` structure, when using the `foreach` loop you actual copy the value of the position on the loop variable, in this case `$image`. Try using this code and it will fix your problem.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($images[1]); $i++)
{

    if($images[1][$i] == 'http://i27.tinypic.com/29yk345.gif' ||

    $images[1][$i] == 'http://img3.abload.de/img/10nx2340fhco.gif' ||

    $images[1][$i] == 'http://i42.tinypic.com/9pp2456x.gif')

    {

        unset($images[1][$i]);

    }

}

var_dump($images);die();
```