# PHP how to delete array values inside foreach loop?

Tags: php

I want to delete the element containing the value 2000   Outside (for example, Eg1,Eg2 and Eg3), This might help: each value loop can have many values.
After remove "2000   Outside" only top record data will display. Eg1 2000 Monday, Eg3 2000  Friday. 
I'm looking for the simplest function to perform this task please.

```
Eg1
Postcode Day
2000    Monday
2000   Outside
2000   Friday
2000   Sunday
2000   wednesday

Eg2
Postcode Day
2000    Outside
2000   Monday
2000   Friday
2000   Sunday
2000   wednesday

Eg3
Postcode Day
2000    Outside
2000   Outside
2000   Friday
2000   Sunday
2000   wednesday

foreach($Items as $item)
{

echo $item->PostCode. " ".$item->Day.'<br/>'."\n";

}
```

Comment: Just remove they key. But that's an object you have there. Still point stands.

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008866/unsetting-array-values-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: I am not clear "remove they key"

Comment: how is it example3 result of 2000 Friday, as it is like example2 where 2000 outside is at the top, based on your criteria, example3 should be empty

Comment: @am05mhz he just wan't to retrieve the first value of array after deleting 2000 Outside element. His examples are correct, no?

Comment: @dlegall if thats the case, example1 should be 2000 Friday too, is it not?

Comment: @am05mhz nop, after deleting 2000 Outside, first element of array is still 2000 Monday

Comment: @dlegall ah, i see now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this :

```
foreach($Items as $key=>$item)
{
    if($item->Postcode == 2000 && $item->Day == "Outside") {
          array_splice($Items,$key,1);
    }
}

echo $Items[0]->Postcode . " " . $Items[0]->Day;
```

Comment: This one not working, all empty

Comment: Strange, I just tested this and it seems to work. Are you sure $Items is empty after passing to the loop ?

Comment: If I add echo $Items[0]->Postcode . " " . $Items[0]->Day; it'll come
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: Can you print_r($Items) and print it here as a comment or in your initial question? I don't get why $Items isn't an array there.

Comment: Only single record will display post code 2029 has only one data record. Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [SubName] => ROSE BAY [PostCode] => 2029 [DeliveryDay] => Tuesday [PeriodType] => weekly [AuState] => NSW

Comment: Post code 2000 has multi records. not print anything print_r($Items)

Comment: I forgotten comment break point. array_splice($Locations,$key,1);
   //break; But now display all records list. I want only display one record. Eg3 2000 Friday.

Comment: I imagine you're putting `echo $Items[0]->Postcode . " " . $Items[0]->Day;` inside the `foreach` loop.  It needs to be after the loop has been closed.

Comment: Any why would you need to break?  That will just remove the first instance which it matched, so in Eg3 you would still have 2000 Outside as the first result unless you ran the `foreach` twice

Comment: I have already removed break. but still display all list. What do I have change your code?

Comment: Can you tell me, this line number 1 without hardcode, how can I add dynamic value?   array_splice($Locations,$key,1); If you convert dynamic value it'll work.

Comment: What do you mean by adding dynamic value?

Comment: because number 1 hardcode, if array has 2nd valves in 'Outside' it'll display only "Outside". Are there any way to loop array and found "Outside" (maybe one or more "Outside") after display first record value day(Monday or Friday). Therefore no need to display "Outside". 
For example some postcode has many records. 1 to 6 value is "Outside", 7 valve is Monday. When I change number 7, array_splice($Locations,$key,7); it'll display Monday

Comment: It's not working like you think it is. This code loop on your array, and each time it match an Outside, it deletes it. The 1 is only here to delete only 1 element, so each time there is an Outside value in your array, it deletes it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I need. but your code multiple record in array 'Outside' not delete only delete first record. If array has second value 'Outside' it won't delete. only delete array has first record  value came 'Outside;

Comment: Can you tell me your php code, first 3 valves are 'Outside' 4th valve is on Monday. Why value is display using $key,1? If I used your code it'll display  'Outside'  If change your code $key,3. It will display on Monday. Why was that? 
'

Comment: Did you let the "break;" I removed some edit before? Using the actual code, every occurences of "2000 Outside" are removed.

Comment: This is print array data
2000 Outside  Area
2000  Outside  Area
2000  Outside  Area
2000  Tuesday

 If I change to your code number 3, array_splice($Items,$key,3);
will display Tuesday. Why was that?

Comment: What array_splice is returned is not important. array_splice delete an element from an array. What you asked is to delete all elements that match 2000 Outside from the array, and display the first element after the deletion. array_splice is deleting each elements that is 2000 Outside. Then you have just to print the first element of the array after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A slight adjustment to dlegall's answer as I was having a bit of trouble getting it to work on my local server.  I've included the array used too.

```
$Items[] = array("Postcode" => 2000, "Day" => "Outside");
$Items[] = array("Postcode" => 2000, "Day" => "Monday");
$Items[] = array("Postcode" => 2000, "Day" => "Friday");

foreach($Items as $key => $item)
    {
        if($item["Postcode"] == 2000 && $item["Day"] == "Outside") {
              array_splice($Items,$key,1);
        }
    }

echo $Items[0]["Postcode"] . " " . $Items[0]["Day"];
```

Comment: This is my input and output details $Items[] = array("Postcode" => 2000, "Day" => "Outside","Day" => "Monday","Day" => "Friday",,"Day" => "Monday");
Result should display Postcode 2000 display first record Monday 
$Items[] = array("Postcode" => 2002, "Day" => "Outside","Day" => "Outside","Day" => "Friday",,"Day" => "Monday");
Result should display Postcode 2002 display second record Friday

Comment: Can you tell me, this line number 1 without hardcode, how can I add dynamic value?   array_splice($Locations,$key,1); If you convert dynamic value it'll work.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic value? his code is already dynamic enough, you can add any value to `$Items` by calling `$Items[] = array('whatever value you want', 'with whatever format');`

Comment: I want only number 1 convert to dynamic valve. array_splice($Items,$key,1); for example a=0; [a]

Comment: because number 1 hardcode, if array has 2nd valves in 'Outside' it'll display only "Outside". Are there any way to loop array and found "Outside" (maybe one or more "Outside") after display first record value day(Monday or Friday). Therefore no need to display "Outside".

Comment: For example some postcode has many records. 1 to 6 value is "Outside", 7 valve is Monday. When I change number 7, array_splice($Locations,$key,7); it'll display Monday

Comment: I'm sorry but I think there is a language barrier here.  Please edit your code and show us EXACTLY how you are making your array, and EXACTLY what you want to do with it.

Comment: Can you tell me your php code, first 3 valves are 'Outside' 4th and fourth valve is on Monday. Which value is display using $key,1? If I used your code it'll display 'Outside' If change your code $key,3. It will display on Monday. Why was that?

Comment: Eg. $Items[] = array("Postcode" => 2000, "Day" => "Outside",  "Day" => "Outside",  "Day" => "Outside",  "Day" => "Monday", "Day" => "Friday"); I need only display first day array value is on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we use the below code ?

```
foreach($array as $element){
 if(($element->postcode == '2000') && ($element->variable == 'Outside')){
  unset($element);
 }
}
```

Comment: variable == '2000' ? or variable == 'Outside'?

Comment: After remove "2000 Outside" how do I display only top record data . Eg1 2000 Monday, Eg3 2000 Friday

Comment: Just to remind, unset() doesn't reorganize indexes of your array, if the array isn't associative. It can lead to errors if that's not specified.