# How to delete elements in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
array() {
  ["AG12345"]=>
  array() { 

  }
  ["AG12548"]=>
  array() { 

  }
  ["VP123"]=>
  array() { 

  }
```

I need to keep only arrays with keys which begin with "VP"

It's possible to do it with one function ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304570/how-to-delete-object-from-array-inside-foreach-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
{
  if(substr($key,0,2)!=="VP")
  {
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, but I'd use `substr()` instead of regexp. It is simpler and faster.

Comment: why is the "!" in there on line 3?

Comment: @crunkchitis - The condition `substr($key,0,2)!=="VP"` checks to see whether the substring consisting of the first two characters of the string `$key` are identical to the string `"VP"`.  In other words, the `!` represents negation.

Comment: @JackManey - I'm new to php so I didn't know "!==" existed, I only knew about "!=". Turns out it was important to what I was working on. Identical vs. equal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From a previous question: [How to delete object from array inside foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304570/how-to-delete-object-from-array-inside-foreach-loop)

```
foreach($array as $elementKey => $element) {
    if(strpos($elementKey, "VP") == 0){
        //delete this particular object from the $array
        unset($array[$elementKey]);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$prefix = 'VP';
for ($i=0; $i <= count($arr); $i++) {
   if (strpos($arr[$i], $prefix) !== 0)
      unset($arr[$i]);
}
```

Comment: That's fair you are OP after all :) but to me substr function will also need another function call i.e. strlen to get the length of the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (this would be way simpler if it were values instead):

```
array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip(preg_grep('~^VP~', array_keys($arr))));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is only a sample how to do this, you have probably many other ways!

```
// sample array
$alpha = array("AG12345"=>"AG12345", "VP12548"=>"VP12548");
foreach($alpha as $val) 
{
    $arr2 = str_split($val, 2);
    if ($arr2[0] == "VP")
        $new_array = array($arr2[0]=>"your_values");
}
```