# How to find object in php array and delete it?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is print_r output of my array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [itemId] => 560639000019
        [name] => Item no1
        [code] => 00001
        [qty] => 5
        [id] => 2
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [itemId] => 470639763471
        [name] => Second item
        [code] => 76347
        [qty] => 9
        [id] => 4
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [itemId] => 56939399632
        [name] => Item no 3
        [code] => 39963
        [qty] => 6
        [id] => 7
    )

)
```

How can I find index of object with [id] => 4 in order to remove it from array?

Comment: Weird thing that after unsetting array item, it breaks json_encode so output becomes unusable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$found = false;  
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->id == 4) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($found) unset($values[$key]);
```

This is considered to be faster then any other solution since we only iterate the `array` to until we find the object we want to remove.

**Note:** You should not remove an element of an array while iterating so we do it afterwards here.

Comment: I'm not sure about the rule of not removing array element while iterating it. In another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304570/how-to-delete-object-from-array-inside-foreach-loop) users were pointing that it is perfectly fine to do so in PHP, so any source on that? Because so far nobody really pointed the reason, just stated it.

Comment: for me it was giving error of object not found so i did it as `$value['id']`

Comment: @MarcinSzulc like 500 years ago, PHP threw an exception if you did that. Thats why people (me, too) have a barrier in the brain for doing so ;-)

Answer (score 9):

```
foreach($parentObj AS $key=>$element){
  if ($element->id == THE_ID_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR){
    echo "Gottcha! The index is - ". $key;
  }
}
```

`$parentObj` is obviously your root array - the one that holds all the others.

We use the `foreach` loop to iterate over each item and then test it's `id` property against what ever value you desire. Once we have that - the `$key` that we are on is the index you are looking for.

Comment: wait .. $element is not an object?

Comment: @lax - I don't follow...What do you mean? The variable `$element` refers to an element within the array...

Comment: $element is an instance of stdClass. See the question

Comment: @lax - I think I see what you mean - its the way you access the property.  I've used the same method as an associative array... My OO PHP is not that strong... but thanks for the comment.  A little more explanation would have gone a long way though...

Comment: @Lix thanks, your answer is also great. I picked other one only because I had to pick one and that was more "complete".

Answer (score 3):

use **[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)**:

```
$a = new stdClass;
$b = new stdClass;
$a->id = 1;
$b->id = 2;

$arr = array($a, $b);
$index = array_search($b, $arr);

echo $index;
// prints out 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach($array AS $key=>$object){
   if($object['id'] == 4){
       $key_in_array = $key;
   }
}

// chop it from the original array
array_slice($array, $key_in_array, 1);
```

Comment: This is almost exactly opposite of what I  want :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the result is to use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$array = array(
    (object)array('id' => 5),
    (object)array('id' => 4),
    (object)array('id' => 3)
);
$array = array_filter($array, function($item) {
    return $item->id != 4;
});
print_r($array);
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however you are iterating over the whole collection although it is not necessary most of the times.

Comment: True, it depends on the situation and certainty of how many elements are there to unset. Though very useful function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. Given, it is a bit hackish, but it will get the job done.

### search(array $items, mixed $id[, &$key]);

Returns the item that was found by `$id`. If you add the variable `$key` it will give you the key of the item found.

```
function search($items, $id, &$key = null) {
  foreach( $items as $item ) {
    if( $item->id == $id ) {
      $key = key($item);
      return $item;
      break;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Usage

```
$item = search($items, 4, $key);
unset($items[$key]);
```

**Note:** This could be modified to allow a custom key and return multiple items that share the same value.

[I've created an example so you can see it in action](http://codepad.org/BxpathBq).

Answer (score 0):

A funny alternative

```
$getIdUnset = function($id) use ($myArray)
{
    foreach($myArray as $key => $obj) {
        if ($obj->id == $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
};

if ($unset = $getIdUnset(4)) {
    unset($myArray[$unset]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently php does not have any supported function for this yet.

So refer to Java's Vector, or jQuery's $.inArray(), it would simply be:

```
public function indexOf($object, array $elementData) {
    $elementCount = count($elementData);
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $elementCount ; $i++){
        if ($object == $elementData[$i]) {
            return $i;   
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You can save this function as a core function for later.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this my array as `$array`
I was confused about this problem of my project, but some answer here helped me.

```
array(3) { 
           [0]=> float(-0.12459619130796) 
           [1]=> float(-0.64018439966448) 
           [2]=> float(0)
         }
```

Then use `if condition` to stop looping

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
           if($key == 0){ //the key is 0
               echo $key; //find the key
               echo $val; //get the value
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, after so many years this could be a useless answer, but why not?

This is my personal implementation of a possible `index_of` using the same code as other answers but let the programmer to choose when and how the check will be done, supporting also complex checks.

```
if (!function_exists('index_of'))
{
    /**
     * @param iterable $haystack
     * @param callable $callback
     * @param mixed|null &$item
     * @return false|int|string
     */
    function index_of($haystack, $callback, &$item = null)
    {
        foreach($haystack as $_key => $_item) {
            if ($callback($_item, $_key) === true) {
                $item = $_item;
                return $_key;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach( $arr as $k=>&$a) {
    if( $a['id'] == 4 )
        unset($arr[$k]);
}
```

Comment: You should never change the array you are currently iterating!

Comment: @fdomig What if there are more than one child with `id` 4?

Comment: @fdomig You can't say that for sure.

Comment: You should never touch the array itself while iterating anyway. You then better add each found index to a `$found` array and remove all keys afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will follow it. Though I still don't understand the point behind it. @fdomig