# Delete the index array from foreach?

Tags: php

Simple question; How can i delete the right Array from my foreach() ?

```
foreach ( $items as $e):
    if ( $e['seat'] == $users[$clientID]['seat']):
        //It's done, delete it.
        unset ( $e );
    endif;
endforeach;
```

unset($e) doesn't seem to work properly. What is the right solution to delete the right array from the right index?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete object from array inside foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304570/how-to-delete-object-from-array-inside-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an alternative to the for-loop given by xbonez, by passing the `key` value as well:

```
foreach ( $items as $key => $e):
    if ( $e['seat'] == $users[$clientID]['seat']):
        //It's done, delete it.
        unset ( $items[$key] );
    endif;
endforeach;
```

I prefer this version, but it doesn't really matter!

Answer (score 1):

Doing `unset($e)` in a `foreach` unsets the variable `$e`, not the item in the array that it represents. You would need to use a a regular for-loop for this

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
   if ($items[$i]['seat'] == $users[$clientID]['seat']) {
      unset($items[$i])
   }
}
```

Comment: `for ($arr as $key => $val)` would be better since your answer is limited to non-associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
foreach ($items as &$e):
    if ($e['seat'] == $users[$clientID]['seat']):
        //It's done, delete it.
        unset ($e);
    endif;
endforeach;
```