# Remove previous element from array if statement == true

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach loop that iterates through an array but I want to check if the array contains $item == 'survey-east-upper' and if that's true then hide the previous $item which is 'survey-east'. I've looked into `in_array` but can't figure how to remove the previous element.

My original code:

```
foreach ($survey_array->Services as $service) {
  foreach ($service as $item) {
    echo '<li title="' . rtrim($item) . '" class="' . strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '-', rtrim($item))) . '">' . $item . '</li>';
    }
  }
```

The new code:

```
foreach ($survey_array->Services as $service) {
  foreach ($service as $item) {
    if (in_array("survey-east-upper", $survey_array->Services)) {
       unset($site->Services['survey-east']);
    }
    echo '<li title="' . rtrim($item) . '" class="' . strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '-', rtrim($item))) . '">' . $item . '</li>';
    }
  }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: One does not simply remove a loop. (Have you tried using a break; to escape the loop)?

Comment: What does `$site->Services` contain? Can you post a dump of its contents?

Comment: I will take a look into breaks. So is the wrong way to go about it?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304570/how-to-delete-object-from-array-inside-foreach-loop

Comment: I would not recommend to edit array with unset od adding during its iterations... it can create confusing code and weird behaviour.

Comment: Sorry George that was mean't to be `$survey_array->Services` not `$site->Services`. Not helpful I know but I'll correct the question.

`stdClass Object (     [SurveyArray] => Array         (             [0] => stdClass Object                 (                     [ServiceName] => SurveyEast                  )              [1] => stdClass Object                 (                     [ServiceName] => SurveyEastUpper                  )          )  ) `

Answer (score 2):

Dont use foreach, use for with indexing. In every iteration, look one item ahead and check that item. If its "survey-east-upper", skip actual iteration and continue further.

```
foreach ($survey_array->Services as $service) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($service) - 1; $i++) {
    $item = $service[$i];
    if ($service[$i + 1] == "survey-east-upper") {
         continue;
    }
    echo '<li title="' . rtrim($item) . '" class="' . strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '-', rtrim($item))) . '">' . $item . '</li>';
    }

  }
```

**Edit:**

You have to do something with last item in array `$service[count($service) - 1]`, because that wont be included in for loop