# how to loop though an array and unset variables in the array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, unset

is there a way to loop through an array and unset any variables that are =""?
i am looking for a faster way to do this aside form writing 4 if else statements.i thought this might work but i don't know if it can be done this way or not.

```
$a=""
$b="123"
$c=""
$d"123"

$var=array($a,$b,$c,$d)
```

i am trying to loop through $var array to get

```
$var= array($b,$d)
```

is this even possible or should i stick with writing 4 if else statements?

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: `$var = array_filter($var);`

Comment: `foreach($var as $k=>$v) if(!isset($v[0])) unset($var[$k]); ` or `$var = array_filter($var)` like @MarkBaker said.

Comment: array_filter that is what i was looking for thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here : [How to delete object from array inside foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304570/how-to-delete-object-from-array-inside-foreach-loop)
or here :
[How do you remove an array element in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949259/how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-in-a-foreach-loop)

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if($value == "") {
    unset($array[$key]);
  } 
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
$x=["","123","","345"];
$var = array_filter($x);
print_r($var);
```

---

The result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 123
    [3] => 345
)
```