# How to unset (remove) a collection element after fetching it?

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a collection which I want to iterate and modify while I fetch some of its elements. But I could't find a way or method to remove that fetched element.

```
$selected = []; 
foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
      if ($collection->selected == true) {
          $selected[] = $value;
          unset($value);
      }
}
```

This is just a representation of my question for demonstration.

After @Ohgodwhy advice the forget() function I checked it again and saw that I actually misunderstood the function. It was exactly as I was looking for.

So for working solution I have added `$collection->forget($key)` inside the if statement.

**Below is the working solution of my problem, using @Ohgodwhy's solution:**

```
$selected = []; 
foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
      if ($collection->selected == true) {
          $selected[] = $value;
          $collection->forget($key);
      }
}
```

(this is just a demonstration)

Comment: I'd suggest not to store your items in an array but create a new collection and adding the elements to it through push.

Comment: @Amarnasan How would go about that? I don't need it right now but I think I may need it in the future

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58769554/655224. your `if` condition `$collection->selected == true` makes no sense. why checking the property `selected` of the `collection` object not of the `value`? if the property is indeed inside `collection` check it once outside of your loop.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You would want to use `->forget()`

```
$collection->forget($key);
```

Link to the [forget method documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forget)

Comment: Yes actually i misunderstood forget(). i thought $key parameter removes all given keys. now i was able to use it right in the loop with a if statement.

Comment: `forget()` is cool compared to `delete()` or `remove()`, but hell, I had to come here to find out how to remove an item :)

Comment: what about if you want to delete entire object?

Comment: @Adamnick With `forget` you'd need to know the `index` of the object in the array. What you want is probably `filter()`

Comment: For anyone looking at this now, the link in the original question is broken, but you can find the same documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-forget

Comment: **this may help someone** <code>                    foreach ($users as $key => $user) 
                    {
                        $user_categories = User_category::where('user_id', $user->id)->exists();
                        if (!$user_categories) 
                        {
                            $users = $users->forget($key); 
                        }
                    }<code>

Answer (score 48):

Or you can use `reject` [method](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_reject)

```
$newColection = $collection->reject(function($element) {
    return $item->selected != true;
});
```

or `pull` [method](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_pull)

```
$selected = []; 
foreach ($collection as $key => $item) {
      if ($item->selected == true) {
          $selected[] = $collection->pull($key);
      }
}
```

Comment: But the reject solution wouldn't remove the elements from the original collection, right?

Comment: Yes, it keeps original collection intact

Comment: Then the perfect solution for the question would be the second one.

Comment: `$collection = $collection->reject(...)` will override the original collection with the new collection. And `$collection->pull(...)` is the best solution i think. The topic heading contains `...after fetching it...`. That is what `pull` does.

Comment: Unfortunatley $collection->links() ceases to work when reject

Answer (score 20):

Laravel `Collection` implements the PHP [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface (which is why using `foreach` is possible in the first place).

If you have the key already you can just use PHP `unset`.

I prefer this, because it clearly modifies the collection in place, and is easy to remember.

```php
foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    unset($collection[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm not fine with solutions that iterates over a collection and inside the loop manipulating the content of even that collection. This can result in unexpected behaviour.

See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2304578/655224 and in a comment the given link http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#88578

So, when using `foreach` it seems to be ok but IMHO the much more readable and simple solution is to filter your collection to a new one.

```
/**
 * Filter all `selected` items
 *
 * @link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-filter
 */
$selected = $collection->filter(function($value, $key) {
    return $value->selected;
})->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods of **Collection** like **pull**, **forget**, **reject** etc.

But every **Collection** method returns an entirely new Collection instance.

Doc link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#introduction

Comment: Your are wrong. "Unlike most other collection methods, forget does not return a new modified collection; it modifies the collection it is called on."

Comment: @Michal-wereda-net this person is not wrong but could have specified in the different context. regardless Ali Akbar Afridi also cited the laravel documentation

Answer (score 0):

> If you know the key which you unset then put directly by comma
>   separated

```
unset($attr['placeholder'], $attr['autocomplete']);
```

Comment: I got a special case I got an item listing system where a new property is being returned in latest properties collection and also in unrated collection which I'm all showing on one page. I want those items already in the first list to be popped out of the second lisg  how do I do this. Keep in mind you can't tell the index the item will appear in. Can I do something like ```$collection->forget($item->id) ``` ?