# Laravel filter the result, that are already filtered

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

**I am getting the available deals here:**

```
$buildQuery = Deals::with(['market:id,name','propertyType:id,name','dealStatus:id,name']);

        if($request->filled('property_type')){
            $buildQuery->where('property_type_id', $request->property_type);
        }

        if($request->filled('purchase_price')){

            $price = explode("-",$request->purchase_price);
            $min_price = (int)$price[0];
            $max_price = (int)$price[1];

            $buildQuery->whereBetween('purchase_price', [$min_price, $max_price]);
        }


        if($request->filled('status')){
            $buildQuery->where('status', $request->status);
        }



        $getDeals = $buildQuery->whereIn('deal_status_id',$dealStatua)
                                ->whereIn('market_id',$getMarket)
                                ->orderBy('id')->get();
```

My problem is when an user selects the `'estimated_profit'` column, i want to do some manual calculation and if it matches the selected value, then do nothing else `remove that row` from *$getDeals* variable,

```
        if($request->filled('estimated_profit')){
            foreach($getDeals as $row){
                $deal = Deal::find($row->id);

                $purchase_price = $deal->purchase_price;
                $cost_of_price = $deal->cost_of_price;
                $arv_price = $deal->arv_price;

                $calculated_estimated_profit = $arv_price - ( $purchase_price + $cost_of_price );

                $price = explode("-",$request->estimated_profit);
                $min_price = (int)$price[0];
                $max_price = (int)$price[1];

                if($calculated_estimated_profit >= $min_price && $calculated_estimated_profit <= $max_price){
                    // dont do anything here
                }else{
                    // dont want that row here
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to remove all occurrences that are not between min and max?

Comment: yes,  *//dont want that row here*, in the else part i dont want that row

Comment: Ok! But do you want to remove these items from the database or object that must return?

Comment: in the object only

Comment: $getDeals = $buildQuery->whereIn('deal_status_id',$dealStatua)
                                ->whereIn('market_id',$getMarket)
                                ->orderBy('id')->get();   
this will return collection, i want to further filter it

Comment: Do you try this

Comment: Tried $date->filter ( but it doesnt seems ti be working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165412/discussion-between-aboubacar-ouattara-and-arun-kumar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try this : `$getDeals->forget($row)` if it does not work, you can try to get the $row index and `$getDeals->forget($index)` ! for other info look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37588625/8489245