# How to remove a selected item from a collection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-collection

I want toa remove an item that is selected from a collection.

```
    $resultCollection = $collection->where('test_key','test_value')->deleteORremove();
    //$collection = [['test_key'=>'test_value','test_key2'=>'test_value'],['test_key'=>'test_value1','test_key2'=>test_value1']]
// $resultCollection = [['test_key'=>'test_value1','test_key2'=>test_value1']]
```

How to do that?

Comment: use this  $collection->forget('key_name');

Comment: and visit this https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_forget

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

[How to unset (remove) a collection element after fetching it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588515/how-to-unset-remove-a-collection-element-after-fetching-)

It is a bit old and I dont know which laravel version you are using so check the documentation

Comment: Thanks, but I wanna delect an item that a test_key equal to test_value
suppose this:
``` 
[
      ['test_key' => 'test_value' , test_key2'=>'a'],['test_key'=>'test_value2' , 'test_key2'=>'b']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation,https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-forget,  what you need is to call the `forget()` method on the collection.

```
$collection->forget('test_key');
$resultCollection = $collection->all();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanna delect an item that a test_key equal to test_value
suppose this:
[
      ['test_key' => 'test_value' , test_key2'=>'a'],['test_key'=>'test_value2' , 'test_key2'=>'b']
]