# Remove row from pagination inside of transform

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

I have a variable that is a pagination object

```
$pagination
```

I am changing things inside of it using transform

```
$pagination->getCollection()->transform(function ($item, $key) use(&$data, &$pagination) {
    $item->foo = 'bar';
}
```

I want to remove an item from the pagination if it meets a certain condition. I don't want it removed until after I've been able to use the data. Following is an example.

```
$pagination->getCollection()->transform(function ($item, $key) use(&$data, &$pagination) {
    $data[] = $item->foo;
    if ($item->foo === 'bar') {
        $item->remove();
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `$pagination->getCollection()->forget($key);` inside of the transform

```
$pagination->getCollection()->transform(function ($item, $key) use(&$data, &$pagination) {
    $data[] = $item->foo;
    if ($item->foo === 'bar') {
        $pagination->getCollection()->forget($key);
    }
}
```

That's from this question.

[How to unset (remove) a collection element after fetching it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588515/how-to-unset-remove-a-collection-element-after-fetching-it/37588625)

I'm guessing the fact I'm dealing with a pagination may be making these answers not apply to my situation.

Answer (score 7):

Doing a separate collection of pagination with `filter()` allows removing items from the pagination based on complex conditions. I return false in the transform and then simply target it in the filter.

```
$pagination = $pagination->getCollection()->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item;
});
```

**Edit:** This actually removed the pagination properties, so I've recreated the pagination afterwards like so

```
// Remove already merged rows
$itemsTransformed = $pagination->getCollection()->filter(function ($item) {
  return $item;
});

// Recreate because filter removed pagination properties
$itemsTransformedAndPaginated = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
  $itemsTransformed,
  $pagination->total(),
  $pagination->perPage(),
  $pagination->currentPage(), [
    'path' => \Request::url(),
    'query' => [
      'page' => $pagination->currentPage()
    ]
  ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer,
the only thing that has to be noted is that when setting pagination properties, use `count($itemsTransformed)` instead of `$pagination->total()`, otherwise the old total count (total count of the not filtered list) would be displayed.