# Unset Element from Array IF

Tags: php

I get some data from the database, which is saved in "$Data". $Data looks like this:

```
        [Data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [PrinterID] => 3
                        [PrinterName] => PRT03_EDV
                        [isDefaultPrinter] => 1
                        [isMapped] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [PrinterID] => 1
                        [PrinterName] => PRT01_Zentral
                        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
                        [isMapped] => 1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [PrinterID] => 2
                        [PrinterName] => PRT02_BH
                        [isDefaultPrinter] => 0
                        [isMapped] => 0
                    )
```

I need to verify, that there is no array in $Data, where "isDefaultPrinter == True" and "isMapped == False". Programatically:

```
if ( $Data["isDefaultPrinter"] == true and $Data["isMapped"] == false ) {
  // Remove from Array
}
```

I did start to code this on my own based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304570/how-to-delete-object-from-array-inside-foreach-loop) and my result was a terrible looking nested loop, which did not work :-(
I am a beginner and I wanted to ask, if there is an nice and easy way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Before you develop some really bad habits, please, *please* use lower case for things like `if`, `and`, and `true`. Although PHP is case insensitive, this isn't standard and looks really broken.

Comment: What "nesting loop"? If you're having trouble with that, please include that code as well.

Comment: I did start to code based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304570/how-to-delete-object-from-array-inside-foreach-loop
I don't know, if this would even be the right way ...

Comment: Do try and keep your questions self-contained. Not everyone is prepared to open a bunch of tabs to try and understand all the parts in your question. It helps especially for those on mobile where they can't really juggle sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version using `array_filter`, which is sort of built for this. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
$valid = array_filter($Data, function($var) {
    return !($var['isDefaultPrinter'] && !$var['isMapped']);
});
```

Comment: I am sure the other answers work as well, but I like this most. It seems to be the thing I was looking for and keeps the code clean. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` to loop over the data array:

```
foreach ($Data['Data'] as $entry) {
    // Examine every entry
    if ($entry['isDefaultPrinter'] && !$entry['isMapped']) {
        // $entry does not meet criteria
    }
}
```

You can write a function that verifies that every entry meets your criteria:

```
function validateData($Data) {
    foreach ($Data['Data'] as $entry) {
        // Examine every entry
        if ($entry['isDefaultPrinter'] && !$entry['isMapped']) {
            // $entry does not meet criteria
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Everything is OK
    return true;
}

var_dump(validateData($Data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unset` to remove the row of the array that doesn't fit your "keep" criteria. You need to know the array key to remove it tidily; this foreach with the `$key` value as well:

```
foreach ($var['Data'] as $key => $entry) {
    // Examine every entry
    if ($entry['isDefaultPrinter'] && !$entry['isMapped']) {
        // $entry does not meet criteria
        unset($var['Data'][$key]);
    }
}

print_r($var); //output remaining values.
```

Once completed - and if you wish - you can then reindex the [outer] array using `array_values()`:

```
$var['Data'] = array_values($var['Data']);
```