# Why value 4 gets printed even after it is deleted from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have written a simple program to understand the effect of deleting an array element inside a foreach loop on that loop.I have noticed that even if i deleted the element 4 ,it still gets printed .Why is that so ?

code :

```
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foreach($arr2 as $elem)
{
    echo '<br>val : '.$elem;

    $index=array_search(4,$arr2); // search for 4 in array

    if($index != false)
    {
       echo ' index :'.$index.' ';

       unset($arr2[$index]); // delete 4 from array 
    }
}
```

output :

```
val : 1 index :3 
val : 2 
val : 3 
val : 4  // 4 gets printed !!
val : 5
```

Comment: use  foreach($arr2 as @elem)

Comment: uh, no don't.. that's not PHP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245061/why-cant-i-unset-a-variable-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Why are you *looking* for the index on every iteration of the array? This could lead to all kinds of strange behavior (e.g. when there are multiple occurrences of the search value). Why not simply filter before the foreach?

Comment: what're your expecting output??

Comment: `<br>val : 1 index :3 <br>val : 2<br>val : 3<br>val : 5`??

Comment: @KrisRoofe yes ................................!

Comment: @AL-zami , [user340764's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493119/6521116) is ok for you. And I think you can put the array_search outside the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line to:

```
foreach($arr2 as &$elem)
```

You should also read about PHP [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). `foreach` works on a copy of your array, not the actual array.

Comment: Thus it would reference the actual data.

Comment: &$elem reference individual data.How it will effect the actual array ?

Comment: @AL-zami By adding ref to $elem instead of modifying the the copy of your $arr2 array created by foreach, you modify the original actual array. Hence when unset($arr2[$index]) executes, it will remove the entry you want from the original array as you expect and not from the copy.