# Deleting an array element within foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a simple array which contains name of all the countries and total number of users registered on my website from that each country. It's something like this:

```
Array (
    [1] => Array ( [name] => Afghanistan [total] => 3 )
    [2] => Array ( [name] => Albania [total] => 0 )
)
```

And, I'm trying to delete array elements (countries) which have 0 users.

I've tried with this code and it's not working:

```
foreach($country as $row) {
    if ($row['total'] == 0) {
        unset($row);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove an array element in a foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949259/how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you `unset($row)` you are only removing the local variable.

Instead fetch the key and remove that:

```
foreach ($country as $i => $row) {
    if ($row['total'] == 0) {
        unset($country[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if you add an `&` sign before `$row` (Pass by reference) ?

Answer (score 3):

Foreach creates copies of the keys/values on the array you're looping over, so all you're doing is unsetting the local copy, not the original that's actually in the array. Either access the array directly

```
foreach($country as $key => $row) {
  if ($row['total'] == 0) {
     unset($country[$key]);
  }
}
```

or use a reference, unset it and filter NULL elements afterwards:

```
foreach($country as &$row) {
    if ($row['total'] == 0) {
        $row = (unset) $row;
    }
}
unset($row);
$country = array_filter($country);
```

Comment: Reference won't work btw. It will still only be a local variable. ;)

Comment: Additionally it's good practise to put the `unset($val)` after the `foreach` loop to remove the reference (this would spare the last paragraph of the answer as well).

Answer (score 0):

Because $row is the value, not the entire element.

Try:
    foreach ($country as $key => $value) {
      if ($row['total'] == 0) {
        unset($country[$key]);
      }
    }