# Removing certain array element in a for-loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have inserted some elements (fruit names) queried from mySQL into an array. Now, I would like to remove certain items from the array. I want to remove 'Apple' and 'Orange' if the exist from the array. This is what I tried but I am getting an error message.

```
Array Example:
Array ( [1] => Orange [2] => Apple)

foreach($terms as $k => $v) 
{
    if (key($v) == "Apple") 
    {
        unset($terms[$k]);
    }
    elseif( key($v) == "Orange")
    {
        unset($terms[$k]);
    }

}


>>> Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given //same error repeated 4 times
```

I referred to this link here: [How do you remove an array element in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949259/how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-in-a-foreach-loop)
I would be grateful if anyone can point out what I did wrong.

Comment: `key()` doesn't work like that. If you're just trying to access the keys of the array, just make use of `$k` provided by your `foreach` construct. In this case, **your array is not associative**, so your keys are numeric and therefore it won't work. Solution would be to either change your array to be associative (eg: `$arr = ['foo' => 'hello', 'bar' => 'howdy'];`), or change the comparison like so: `if ($v == 'SomeValue') { /* do stuff */ }`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks for the explanation. I just started php not long ago and still learning from examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation:

The `$fr` is your actual array of all fruits.. and your `$rm` is another array that contains list of items to be removed from your `$fr` array.

Using a `foreach` cycle through the `$rm` array and see if the element exists on the `$fr` array , if found, `unset()` it.

#### The code...

```
<?php
$fr = array('Apple','Orange','Pineapple'); //<-- Your actual array
$rm = array('Apple','Orange'); //<--- Elements to be removed 

foreach($rm as $v)
{
    if(in_array($v,$fr))
    {
        unset($fr[array_search($v,$fr)]);
    }
}
print_r($fr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [2] => Pineapple
)
```

#### Using `array_diff()`

```
print_r(array_diff($fr,$rm));
```

<kbd>[Code Demonstration](https://eval.in/139434)</kbd>

Comment: Or you could just use `array_diff($fr, $rm)`.

Comment: @AmalMurali, Exactly.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Thanks! It's great to know I can do that and yes that would help. I just started php 2 days ago and still have lots to learns.

Comment: @Cryssie, We are glad to help you :)

Comment: @Cryssie, Instead of checking for each and every time , better store them in an array and utilize the available powerful array functions and you could also lessen your code using the same.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried it this way:

```
foreach($terms as $k => $v) 
{ 
    if ($v == "Apple") 
    {
        unset($terms[$k]);
    }
    elseif($v == "Orange")
    {
        unset($terms[$k]);
    }

}
```

Comment: While the selected answer is more structurally sound this is a good answer for highlighting the actual current value in the foreach loop ($v)