# Why isn't unset removing index.php from it's

Tags: php, foreach, unset

Why won't unset remove index.php from the results I am echoing out?

```
$files = array(
    '0' => 'bob.php',
    '1' => 'index.php',
    '2' => 'fred.php'
);
foreach ($files as $key => &$file) {
    if(in_array($file, array('index.php'))) {
        echo 'test condition<br />'; // Yes, this condition is met
        unset($files[$key]);
    }
    echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br />'."\n"; 
}
```

To make this I actually followed the answers for [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949259/how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-in-a-foreach-loop).

Comment: You're just removing an entry from the `$files` array. That doesn't unset the local `$file` string **nor skip** the subsequent `echo`.

Comment: Apparently unsetting the array index doesn't affect the reference variable. You have to assign something to the array index to change the reference.

Comment: What are you expecting it to echo after you remove the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$file` is already set to `index.php` it still echos. The key is in-fact unset though, and you can fix the code by using a `continue` in the loop:

```
<?php

$files = array("home.php","index.php","example.php");
    foreach ($files as $key => &$file) {
        if(in_array($file, array('index.php'))) {
            unset($files[$key]);
            continue;
        }
        echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br />'."\n"; 
    }
?>
```

Result:

```
<a href="home.php">home.php</a><br />
<a href="example.php">example.php</a><br />
```