# Remove string from PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Is it possible to remove a string (see example below) from a PHP array without knowing the index?

**Example:**

```
array = array("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5");
```

I need to remove string3.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
$index = array_search('string3',$array);
if($index !== FALSE){
    unset($array[$index]);
}
```

if you think your value will be in there more than once try using [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with a search value to get all of the indexes.  You'll probably want to make sure

EDIT:

Note, that indexes remain unchanged when using `unset`.  If this is an issue, there is a nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/369761/176140) that shows how to do this using `array_splice`.

Comment: I like this +1 for you. But, how can I confirm that it was removed (display on screen)?

Comment: Check out the php functions print_r and var_dump.  You can use them to dump the contents of your array.

Comment: note that using unset() will keep indexes untouched: http://stackoverflow.com/a/369761/176140

Comment: `array_values` is easier to use than `array_splice` for cleaning up the indexes.

Comment: You should use `if($index)` instead of `if($index !== FALSE)`, it looks cleaner and still works.

EDIT: NEVERMIND, it will not work if the string to be removed if it is on index 0.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably not the fastest method, but it's a short and neat one line of code:

```
$array = array_diff($array, array("string3"))
```

or if you're using PHP >5.4.0 or higher:

```
$array = array_diff($array, ["string3"])
```

Comment: I bench-marked you method against GWW's in a for loop that runs 2.5 million times. Your's completed in 18 seconds (17 seconds when I didn't use variables), whereas GWW's completed in 16 seconds. So `array_diff` is slower as is deals with an array instead of a single string, causing overhead.

If only there were a function like `array_diff` but for removing a single string in an array.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 slower but no that much slower, that's only about 5-10% difference which is not worth losing sleep over unless you deal with hundreds of thousands of records, and it might be even less in PHP8 now

Answer (score 5):

You can do this.

```
$arr = array("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5");
$new_arr=array();
foreach($arr as $value)
{
    if($value=="string3")
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        $new_arr[]=$value;
    }     
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a combination of `array_search` and `array_splice`.

```
function array_remove(&$array, $item){
  $index = array_search($item, $array);
  if($index === false)
    return false;
  array_splice($array, $index, 1);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try like this.

```
$array = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"];
$key = array_search('string3',$array);
unset($array[$key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sort of depends how big the array is likely to be, and there's multiple options.

If it's typically quite small, array_diff is likely the fastest consistent solution, as Jorge posted.

Another solution for slightly larger sets:

```
$data = array_flip($data);
unset($data[$item2remove]);
$data = array_flip($data);
```

But that's only good if you don't have duplicate items. Depending on your workload it might be advantageous to guarantee uniqueness of items too.