# How can i delete a item at index X in array?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete an element from an array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php)

I have a list of things, cars for instance

```
$cars[0] = "audi";
$cars[1] = "saab";
$cars[2] = "volvo";
$cars[3] = "vw";
```

How do i delete "volvo" from the list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$volvoIndex = array_search('volvo', $cars);
unset($cars[$volvoIndex]);
```

Comment: damn. you write faster than me! :P btw. +1 ;)

Answer (score 4):

you can do with unset

```
unset($cars[2]);
```

But after that you need to iterate array with `foreach`

Comment: If you follow this up by doing `$cars = array_filter($cars)` it will remove the empty array items as well. :)

Comment: What happens if "volvo" is array item 3?

Comment: @Merjin What do you mean by "empty array item"?

Comment: Whoops. I meant 'empty strings' but I just tried and unset also removes the item from the array. No empty spaces left to trim, so ignore my other comment.

Comment: upvoting you to [enable you to closevote the question](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon I used what rights I got right now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following thing to delete the x element from array

```
array_splice($cars,2,1)
```

This will delete the 2nd element in array and return the remaining array, if you want more elemetns to be deleted change 1 to number of elements that needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

use this for example: `unset($cars[2]);`