# Exclude an ID from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-unset

How can I exclude a certain ID being pulled from an array on the below?

```
<?php echo $EM_Category->id; ?>
```

The array is pulling all ID's but I want to exclude a specific one and include the rest.

Would it be by using `unset` to remove the specific ID?

Comment: I don't see an array in your question

Comment: There are a ton of ways to exclude it; it depends on what a lot of your code look like.  Do you have control over the building of the array or just the display?  Are you displaying in a loop?

Comment: That's an object, not an array

Comment: @RonnieT: Can you show the code with the array or do you want to unset an object property? Or is that a dynamic property even based on some array inside the object?

Comment: Almost has the same title as yours... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can usset it or use `array_diff_key()`.

PS. Your code doesn't make sense. You claim to have a bunch of IDs, but you are echoing just one. Probably you need to paste in some more of your code.