# Delete element from array if not found

Tags: php, parsing

I have some code I created which is supposed to see if something exists in an array of strings. If it does not exist, I want to delete that element of the array. I thought we do this with `unset`, but it doesnt seem to be working. Mind helping?

```
echo '<br>size of $games before end-check: '.sizeof($games);
foreach ($games as $game) {
    $game_end_marker = "body = (game)#";
    $game_end_pos = strpos($game, $game_end_marker);
    if ($game_end_pos !== false) {
        echo "<br>end of game found";
    } 
    else {
        echo "<br>end of game not found. incomplete game";
        unset($game);
    }
}
echo '<br>size of $games after end-check: '.sizeof($games);
```

output:

```
size of $games before end-check: 2  
end of game found  
end of game not found. incomplete game  
size of $games after end-check: 2
```

Comment: you should unset from $games not $game, $game is temporary created by the foreach function.

Comment: Refer this answer: [How to delete an element from an array in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/369761/500725)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you unset the variable $game, not the element in the array. Try this:

```
echo '<br>size of $games before end-check: '.sizeof($games);
foreach ($games as $index => $game) {
    $game_end_marker = "body = (game)#";
    $game_end_pos = strpos($game, $game_end_marker);
    if ($game_end_pos !== false) {
        echo "<br>end of game found";
    } 
    else {
        echo "<br>end of game not found. incomplete game";
        unset($games[$index]);
    }
}
echo '<br>size of $games after end-check: '.sizeof($games);
```

Comment: This did the trick, and I learned how to do this now with $key => $value in a foreach loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to unset the index of game.

```
foreach ($games as $key => $value) {
  // all your logic here, performed on $value
  unset($games[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This merely unsets your local reference to the element. You need to be referring directly to the array.

```
foreach($games as $key => $game)
    unset($games[$key]);
```

Comment: I marked an identical solution above, but yes - this is the correct answer! Thank you

Comment: @pr0tocol his was a more complete solution. Glad I could help.

Comment: Yes, but don't want to take anything away from you. I appreciate the time

Answer (score 0):

That won't work: `foreach` creates a new variable, copying the old one. Unsetting it will do nothing to the original value. Likewise, making it a reference won't work either, since only the reference would be deleted.

The nicest way to do this would be with [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$games = array_filter($games, function($game) {
    $game_end_marker = "body = (game)#";
    $game_end_pos = strpos($game, $game_end_marker);

    if ($game_end_pos !== false) {
        echo "<br>end of game found";
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        echo "<br>end of game not found. incomplete game";
        return false;
    }
});
```

This uses the anonymous function syntax introduced in PHP 5.3. If the function returns `true`, the element is kept; if it returns `false`, the element is removed.

Comment: I marked the answer above, and this is incorrect per the implemented solution results. Using `foreach ($games as $index => $game)`, I was able to do `unset($games[$index])` and it persisted outside of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call by reference:

```
foreach($games as &$game) {
    unset($game);
}
```

In this way you can also change `$game` (eg. `$game .= " blah";`) and the original array will be modified.

Comment: No, that will have no effect. Calling `unset` on a reference will only delete the reference, not the original value.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. But the reference thing still applies for the changing values, so I'll leave that in case it's useful to the asker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_splice` in conjunction with an incrementally-increasing index variable to remove the current item from the array:

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($games as $game) {
    $game_end_marker = "body = (game)#";
    $game_end_pos = strpos($game, $game_end_marker);
    if ($game_end_pos !== false) {
        echo "<br>end of game found";
    } 
    else {
        echo "<br>end of game not found. incomplete game";
        array_splice($games, $index, 1);
    }
$index++;
}
```