# How do I delete an item in an array that is in a session? php

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a session that contains an array. The array contains the following data:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => /assets/img/user_photos/thumbs/9c2310c2def9981221ec37cbbafe0370.jpg 
    [1] => /assets/img/user_photos/thumbs/286b59eb3dafe2e0cf0df50e45f10250.jpg 
    [2] => /assets/img/user_photos/thumbs/4e6012cc396252594d2a05850b0a35ae.jpg 
    [3] => /assets/img/user_photos/thumbs/49ce9031319203c1911c0b9789a83ffc.jpg 
    [4] => /assets/img/user_photos/thumbs/da21379f3dc80541a087e1c4db5f929a.jpg 
    [5] => /assets/img/user_photos/thumbs/1f46378fdd7dcf7fda580e50ca92a2d0.jpg 
)
```

I would like to delete an item from this array. How is this possible when the array is stored in a session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [unset](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to delete elements from an array.

```
unset($array[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

in a non-hacked Environment the superglobal-Array $_SESSION references all data in the session.
So you could delete an entry by this:

```
unset($_SESSION['indexToYourArray'][0]);
```

(you didn't mention in which session variable your index is stored). If the array is the session content the code should read:

```
unset($_SESSION[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
unset($_SESSION['Array_name']['index_tobe_delete']);
```

OR

```
$_SESSION['Array_name']['index_tobe_delete'] = "" ;
```

Comment: That second one, with the `==`, will only compare, not unset.

Comment: -1, even with `= ""` it will not unset but rather set it to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unset()`

**Eg:**

```
$_SESSION['abc'] =  Array ('foo','bar');
```

to delete `bar`:

```
unset($_SESSION['abc'][1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use unset

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['array'][0]);
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could unset the array item:

```
unset($_SESSION['array'][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3);

unset($array[2]);
$array = array_values($array);
var_dump($array);
```

and for more info read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($_SESSION['array_name']);
```

Comment: This would unset their whole array, instead of just the one item.