# How to remove products from a JSON-formatted list? (using an ID)

Tags: php, json

here is an example of the JSON generated from values retrieved from my database:

```
    {
    "product": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "producta",
            "size": "50",
            "weight": "1000",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "productb",
            "size": "50",
            "weight": "1000",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "productb",
            "size": "10",
            "weight": "9000",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title": "productd",
            "size": "100",
            "weight": "500",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "4"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "title": "producta",
            "size": "45",
            "weight": "880",
            "quantity": "120",
            "cartID": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

When the user selects to remove an item from the shopping cart, the variable **$remove_cartid** is passed to  my PHP page. If  **$remove_cartid = 4**, then the **product** with **"cartID": "4"** must be removed:

```
    {
    "product": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "producta",
            "size": "50",
            "weight": "1000",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "productb",
            "size": "50",
            "weight": "1000",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "productb",
            "size": "10",
            "weight": "9000",
            "quantity": "100",
            "cartID": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "title": "producta",
            "size": "45",
            "weight": "880",
            "quantity": "120",
            "cartID": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have made several attempts using the PHP explode function to try and remove the product from the JSON list, but I feel that there is a better way (one that will actually work)

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$list = json_decode($jsonList, true);

foreach ($list['product'] as $key => $product) {
    if ($product['cartID'] == $remove_cartid) {
        unset($list['product'][$key]);
    }
}

$jsonList = json_encode($list);
```

Comment: There are so many smart people in the world. Jesus. Thank you so much deceze