# Remove a value from an array if in it

Tags: php, arrays, ip

I'm currently developing a simple IP ban system that bans an IP if something is done twice. I have searched but it seems that the answers I find are ones that use foreach. What I am wondering, is how to remove a value from an array to tidy it up?

code:

```
function ipCheck($ip) {
$ip1 = array();
$ip2 = array();
if(in_array($ip, $ip2, true)){
    die();
}
elseif(in_array($ip, $ip1){
    array_push($ip2, $ip);
else{
    array_push($ip1, $ip);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: May be this link can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php

Comment: Is there a way to find out the location of the element if it is found in the array?(the number like $a[1])

Comment: Use `$index = array_search($ip, $ip_array);`. [`array_splice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) will return `false` (use `===` or `!==` to check) if it's not in the array, otherwise it will have the 0-based index of the element.

Comment: You got your anser from @soxxeh :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if(isset($array[$ip]) {
    unset($array[$ip]);
}
```