# Get and remove first element of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, get

Hi I am coding a system in which I need a function to get and remove the first element of the array. This array has numbers i.e.

0,1,2,3,4,5

how can I loop through this array and with each pass get the value and then remove that from the array so at the end of 5 rounds the array will be empty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at [`array_shift`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php

Comment: `array_shift` will do that, but do you really need to empty the array incrementally?

Comment: not a duplicate, i don't have the key to unset it, i am looping through. yes needs to be emptied incrementally. I looked at array_shift but couldn't tell weather it removes that array item after returning it...

Comment: As stated in the documentation @sachleen linked: "array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element"

Comment: That's what I thought when i read it but i tried it but it didn't work...

Comment: Am trying a different approach, instead of interating with a while, going to use a foreach, no need to delete and use the first in the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try using foreach/unset, instead of array_shift.

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

foreach($array as $value)
{
    // with each pass get the value
    // use method to doSomethingWithValue($value);
    echo $value;
    // and then remove that from the array 
    unset($array[$value]);
}
//so at the end of 6 rounds the array will be empty
assert('empty($array) /* Array must be empty. */');
?>
```

Comment: This answer works by happenstance (keys and values are identical) and is misleading to readers.  It is not a reliable approach to use `unset($array[$value])` in the wild.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) for this:

```
while (($num = array_shift($arr)) !== NULL) {
  // use $num
}
```