# find matching link in text file with php

Tags: php, regex, file-get-contents

I have a function to read a text file and cross match with a directory search to maths the descriptions (text file) with a directory index for files. I used the leveltensin function to give some fuzzy logic so names don't need to be 100% identical but i'm running into a snag, as I have it set up now i'm hetting a memory wall because when i uncomment the lines below it searches the entire txt file and compares every single ling against the directory file name. With over 700 files each being checked 700 times i quickly run out of memory. i need some way to jump out of the while (!feof($file_handle) ) when it finds a match then find some way to set the starting point for the next pass to the line position we stopped it so it isint looping 0-700 every single time

```
function GenerateList($titleB, $descB, $thumbB, $dirB, $patternB){
$outputB = "<CATEGORY name=\"$titleB\" desc=\"$descB\" thumb=\"$thumbB\">";
$open_error = 0;

if (is_dir($dirB)){
$myDirectory = opendir($dirB);
// get each entry
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

// close directory
closedir($myDirectory);

//  count elements in array
$indexCount = count($dirArray);

// sort em
sort($dirArray);
// loop through the array of files and print them all
if (!($text = file_get_contents("Scripts/descriptions.txt"))){$open_error = 1;}
$results = array();
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    $ext = explode(".", $dirArray[$index]);
    $parsed_title = preg_replace ($patternB, "", $ext[0]);
    if ((substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".")&&($ext[1] == "flv")){ // don't list hidden files

//if ($open_error == 0){
//  $file_handle = fopen("Scripts/descriptions.txt", "rb");

//while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
//$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
//$parts = explode('|', $line_of_text);
/*
echo "<PRE>";
echo strtolower($parts[0]);
echo "</br>";
echo strtolower($parsed_title);
echo "</br>";
echo "</PRE>";
*/
//if ((wordMatch(strtolower($parts[0]), strtolower($parsed_title), 2)) > 0){
        $outputB .= "<ITEM>";
        $outputB .= "<file_path>/Sources/Power Rangers/$dirB".$dirArray[$index]."</file_path>";
        $outputB .= "<file_width>500</file_width>";
        $outputB .= "<file_height>375</file_height>";
        $outputB .= "<file_title>".$parsed_title."</file_title>";
//      $outputB .= "<file_desc>".$parts[1]."</file_desc>";
        $outputB .= "<file_desc>test</file_desc>";
//      $outputB .= "<file_image>".$match_result[2]."</file_image>";
        $outputB .= "<file_image>$thumbB</file_image>";
//      $outputB .= "<featured_image>".$match_result[3]."</featured_image>";
        $outputB .= "<featured_image>$thumbB</featured_image>";
//      $outputB .= "<featured_or_not>".$parts[4]."</featured_or_not>";
        $outputB .= "<featured_or_not>true</featured_or_not>";
        $outputB .= "</ITEM>";
//};//if ((wordMatch($parts[0], strtolower($word), 2) > 0)
//};//while
//fclose($file_handle);

//};//if ($open_error == 0)
    };//if ((substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".")&&($ext[1] == "flv"))
};//for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
};//if (file_exists($dirB))
$outputB .= "</CATEGORY>";
return $outputB;
};//function

    function wordMatch($words, $input, $sensitivity){ 
        $shortest = -1; 
        foreach ($words as $word) { 
            $lev = levenshtein($input, $word); 
            if ($lev == 0) { 
                $closest = $word; 
                $shortest = 0; 
                break; 
            } //if
            if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) { 
                $closest  = $word; 
                $shortest = $lev; 
            } //if
        } //foreach
        if($shortest <= $sensitivity){ 
            return $closest; 
        } else { 
            return 0; 
        } //if/else
    } // function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php
```

Comment: How do you define "80%"?  A regex either matches or it doesn't.

Comment: thats the tricky part if $parsed is say "Peace Love and Woe" and matches is "Peace Love & Woe" or "Peace Love andWoe" or "Peace Love and Woe.avi" it should all be valid

Comment: So ... your "80%" rule isn't so much a defined rule as it is a thing you would like help defining?  Have you considered [fuzy logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic)?  You won't be able to implement it in a regular expression, but it might get you closer to your goal.  ALSO, including some sample data (along with your idea of how much a match it represents) would make it easier to write something that actually matches your requirements.

Comment: samples are easy enough the parsed Data is the left menu here http://maskedriders.info/Sources/Power%20Rangers/ while the file is here http://maskedriders.info/Sources/Power%20Rangers/Scripts/descriptions.txt the idea is I want to match in the txt with the parsed title so i can load into my xml data in the other fields after the | on the txt

Comment: as for Fuzzy logic after explaining it i was thinking "ifi just strip out ehite spaces, (), and convert any & to and and cast it all to lower case" it should fill the 80% rule the problem is i would have to do the same to the text file but only before |

Comment: Sounds like you have a tentative solution.  Why don't you try it out, and if there are still challenges, see what the intelligentsia of StackOverflow can offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a regex, you can compute the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between the two items.  Your 80% heuristic would then be equivalent to saying that `(length-edit_distance)/length >= .8` where `length` is the length of the string you're trying to match.

So if the string was 20 chars long and the edit distance from your target was 2, you would calculate that `(20-2) / 20 == .9`  In other words, that item was a 90% match to your target.  That's higher than .8, so you accept it as a match.

Note that 'edit distance' is also known as [Levenshtein distance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php), so you just do something like:

```php
$len = (float) strlen($target);  // Avoids integer division.
$match = ($len-levenshtein($input, $target))/$len;

if ($match >= 0.8) {
  // The $input matches our $target
}
```

Comment: Nice idea. If you can include (or point to) some example code that calculates edit distance between strings in PHP, that would definitely get you StackOverflow points.  :)

Comment: There is also the issue of searching a txt file for a link matchingthe huristics, i'd really like to avoid loading the extire TXT into a variable or array only to discard most of it since i have to loop through it about 700 times to populate the xml file for each entry

Comment: I think edit distance is a PHP function already?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php  As for the rest, don't all your links start with http:// or https://?  You could just pull out everything that looks like a link, then do your fuzzy matching stuff.

Comment: ok i think I'm getting somewhere but ive run into a snag, check the modified OP to see the problem

Comment: What's the snag?  The question looks the same to me?

Comment: wow your fast i was still updating the OP when you were reading, check now

Comment: This would have been better as a new question, given that this one is already "answered" so people may not look at it much.  Anyhow, the problem is with how you're calling this.  It looks like you're doing GenerateList 700 times.  You need to invert things so that you go through each file *once* and keep attempting to match an individual line against whatever until you either find a match or find that nothing will match it.  Then it will be simple to skip to the next line whenever you have a match.

Comment: the problem is that WordMatch requires 2 paramaneters the first is the  txt file the second is the directory so i need access to both to do a match check

Comment: The `WordMatch` code I see has only a list of words, a target word, and a sensitivity?  Where does it take a directory?

Comment: the first parameter is fed from the txt file (though i should probably change it from acceptiong a araay to a single string input), the second is the match target thats $parsed_title currently which is the current file indexed from the directory, the 3rd is sensativity.
So wordMatch is comparting a txt file against a arrayposition (dirctory) and seeing if they match with a sensativity of 2

Comment: If you're going for a bunch of 1-to-1 matches, slurp that whole text file into an array (kind of like you do with the directories), then remove the matched items from both arrays after you have generated your output.

( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php )

Comment: gonna create a new discussion to go on from here