# Removing a value from an array php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there an easier way to do so?

```
$array = array(1,57,5,84,21,8,4,2,8,3,4);
$remove = 21;   
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $value ){
    if( $value == $remove)
        unset($array[$i])
        $i++;
    }

//array: 1,57,5,84,8,4,2,8,3,4
```

Comment: That's one way to do it. You could also use array_splice(). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `array_search` answer is good.  You could also `arraydiff` like this

```
$array = array(1,57,5,84,21,8,4,2,8,3,4);
$remove = array(21);
$result = array_diff($array, $remove);
```

Comment: Doh, I thought of the same answer as yours.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delete the *first* occurrence of the item in the array, use [`array_search`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the index of the item in the array rather than rolling your own loop.

```
$array = array(1,57,5,84,21,8,4,2,8,3,4);
$remove = 21;

$index = array_search($remove, $array);

if (index !== false)
  unset($array[$index]);
```

To remove all duplicates, rerun the search/delete so long as it finds a match:

```
while (false !== ($index = array_search($remove, $array))) {
  unset($array[$index]);
}
```

or find all keys for matching values and remove them:

```
foreach (array_keys($array, $remove) as $key) {
  unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Comment: This is assuming the value in only in the array once.  Otherwise, you can use `array_keys` (with the 2nd parameter).

Comment: This will only work for the first match what about duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little cleaner:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $remove) {
        unset($array[$key]);
        break;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, you can place the non-matching values into a temp array, then reset the original.

```
$temp = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != $remove) {
        $temp[$key] = $value;
    }
}
$array = $temp;
```

Comment: That's assuming it's only in there once.

Comment: This is no better than the solution proposed in the question. You should never roll your own loop when built-in functionality will do the job for you. In particular when PHP provides a built-in function for doing something, you should never duplicate that functionality with a hand-rolled loop. `array_search` is orders of magnitude faster than `foreach`.

Comment: @meagar that explains the lack of up-votes :-/ I realize it's not as efficient as `array_search` and `array_diff`, which is why I up-voted your and Mike's answers. Cheers!