# Count from a specific array in explode

Tags: php, explode

Is it possible to count from a specific array in explode?

#### Example:

```
<?php
$number='This is the number of,5,6,7,8,9';
$collect=explode(",",$number);
print_r($collect);
?>
```

#### Output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => This is the number of [1] => 5 [2] => 6 [3] => 7 [4] => 8 [5] => 9 )
```

But I need to ignore the first array. Meaning, that I want to count only `5,6,7,8,9` and ignore `"This is the number of"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the below code instead of yours... here I am just adding a new line... the 4th one...

```
<?php
$number='This is the number of,5,6,7,8,9';
$collect=explode(",",$number);
array_shift($collect); // remove the first index from the array
print_r($collect);
?>
```

Output:

```
 Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 [4] => 9 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unset($collect[0]);
```

See
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

and

[Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: This is bad because array elements will be counted from 1, not from 0. It's unexpected behaviour in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to remove first element of the array.

You wrote "I want to ignore first array" but you obviously meant "array element". Note that "array" is the whole output of `explode` function.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

Directly you can remove the first element of the array:

```
$number='This is the number of,5,6,7,8,9';
$collect=explode(",",$number);
unset($collect[0]);
print_r($collect);
```

But briefly, you should use regular expressions so you match only the numbers:

```
preg_match_all('/,(\d+)/, explode(",",$number), $collect);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Thanks. But i am new in php . so it is hard for me to use this function. Again thanks to inform me a new things.