# PHP: array_diff - remove one value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently trying to use array_diff to remove 1 value from an array.

The code looks like this right now:

```
$item_id = 501;
$array = array_diff($user_items, array($item_id));
```

user items array: 501,501,502,502

results correctly in array: 502,502

Is it possible to remove only 1x501 instead of 2x501 value? or said differently: limit the removal by 1 value

array is then: 501,502,502

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about searching for the item, then removing it if it exists?

```
$key = array_search($item_id, $user_items)
if ($key !== FALSE) {
  unset($user_items[$key]);
}
```

Using `unset` isn't quite as straightforward as you'd think. See Stefan Gehrig's answer in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php/369761) for details.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find and remove the first value:

```
$pos = array_search($item_id, $user_items);

if($pos !== false)
  unset($user_items[$pos]);
```

Comment: The OP wanted to remove one value only. If he wants them all out, then `array_diff` would be a better choice

Comment: That *is* what my code does. Take another look or try running it and output the results.

Comment: Yes, I see now that you're iterating the needles. Still, only one replacement is needed *in this case*, so there's no point in using a loop