# How to delete duplicates in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I delete duplicates in array?

For example if I had the following array:

```
$array = array('1','1','2','3');
```

I want it to become

```
$array = array('2','3');
```

so I want it to delete the whole value if two of it are found

Comment: http://php.net/array_count_values <- I would try to write something with this function first. It counts at least how often one value has been used. Nicely keyed.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on PHP version, this should work in all versions of PHP >= 4.0.6 as it doesn't require anonymous functions that require PHP >= 5.3:

```
function moreThanOne($val) {
    return $val < 2;
}


$a1 = array('1','1','2','3');
print_r(array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($a1), 'moreThanOne')));
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb26364014c76fcd14a036bcad9f703fd328d6fd) (Change the PHP version in the drop-down to select the version of PHP you are using)

This works because:

1. [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) will go through the array and create an index for each value and increment it each time it encounters it again.
2. [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will take the created array and pass it through the `moreThanOne` function defined earlier, if it returns `false`, the key/value pair will be removed.
3. [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will discard the `value` portion of the array creating an array with the values being the keys that were defined.  This final step gives you a result that removes all values that existed more than once within the original array.

Comment: Anonymous functions were introduced in 5.3

Comment: Good point, so to modify the "not just PHP 5.4" it will be "for PHP > 4.0.6" ^^

Comment: It would work in 4.0.6 too, which is when `array_filter` was introduced :)

Comment: +1 good usage of native php-functions. Well explained and a demo.

Comment: Grr @jack =P Lol, again, good point, maybe to tired to be creating version requirements for code. =]

Answer (score 4):

You can filter them out using [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values):

```
$array = array('1','1','2','3');
$res = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($array), function($freq) {
    return $freq == 1;
}));
```

The function returns an array comprising the original values and their respective frequencies; you then pick only the single frequencies. The end result is obtained by retrieving the keys.

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/phmXJd)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
<?php
  $array = array('1','1','2','3');

 foreach($array as $data){
  $key= array_keys($array,$data);
   if(count($key)>1){

  foreach($key as $key2 => $data2){
    unset($array[$key2]);
      }
    }
   }
   $array=array_values($array);
   print_r($array);


?>
```

Output

```
    Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP offers so many [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), you just have to combine them:

```
$arr = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($arr), function($val) {
    return $val === 1;
}));
```

Reference: [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [`array_count_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/twtwUs)

Answer (score 2):

Remove duplicate values from an array.

```
 array_unique($array)

 $array = array(4, "4", "3", 4, 3, "3");
 $result = array_unique($array);
 print_r($result);

 /*
   Array
   (
      [0] => 4
      [2] => 3
   )
  */
```