# Php array duplicates separation

Tags: php, sorting

In PHP I have a arrays of id

```
$ids = array(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3);
```

I just wanted to separate the 1 which will become `1, 1, 1` and 2 become `2, 2` and 3 become `3, 3`.
How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: its hard to get what your expected output is. can you give a code example?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372292/how-to-delete-duplicates-in-an-array[/link] Already answered here.

Comment: Do you want three arrays of one string? Like: `array('1, 1, 1'), array('2, 2'), ...`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [array_count_values](http://php.net/array_count_values) to find out how many times each element occurs in the array. You won't have `{1, 1, 1}` but you'll have `[1] => 3` which I hope amounts to the same thing for your use.

Answer (score 4):

This could easily be done by a simple loop:

```
$ids = array(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3);

foreach($ids as $id){
    $new[$id][] = $id;
}

print_r($new);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
$ids = array(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3);
foreach($ids as $key) {
    //Calculate the index to avoid duplication
    if(isset(${"arr_$key"})) $c = count(${"arr_$key"}) + 1;
    else $c = 0;
    ${"arr_$key"}[$c] = $key;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/xYSQG3J2)

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want distinct array values (no repetition). If so, then here goes:

```
$ids = array(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3);
$distinct_ids = array_values(array_unique($ids));
```

to give the output as

```
array (size=3)
0 => int 1
1 => int 2
2 => int 3
```

`array_unique` removes duplicate values from the array, while `array_value` resets the array keys.

Documentation: [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php), [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)