# How to remove duplicates and the original one from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I delete duplicates in a multidimensional array?
I tried several answers found on stackoverflow but none of them works for me in an multi array. The closest answer i found was this:

[How to delete duplicates in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372292/how-to-delete-duplicates-in-an-array)
But that only worked on a single-dimensional array.

For example i have this:

```
$array = array(
    [0] = array(
        [color] => red,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color1
    )
    [1] = array(
        [color] => gray,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color2
    )
    [2] = array(
        [color] => blue,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color3
    )
    [3] = array(
        [color] => green,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color4
    )
    [4] = array(
        [color] => black,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color5
    )
    [3] = array(
        [color] => gray,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color2
    )
    [4] = array(
        [color] => blue,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color3
    )
)
```

How can i let it become this:?

```
$array = array(
    [0] = array(
        [color] => red,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color1
    )
    [1] = array(
        [color] => gray,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color2
    )
    [2] = array(
        [color] => blue,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color3
    )
    [3] = array(
        [color] => green,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color4
    )
    [4] = array(
        [color] => black,
        [type] => color,
        [name] => color5
    )
)
```

Comment: Your input and output doesn't make sense. How to you filter our "gray" for example? It's not clear.

Comment: I though it might be possible to filter out the duplicate row and the original. So array 1 matches array 3. Delete both rows.

Comment: Read awnser. It does what i asked. So 'not possible at all' kinda wierd awnser

Comment: @RichardMauritz  it's possible(i know,i answered also), what i am saying that keys 3,4,3,4 that's not possible, because identical keys will over-write previous one

Comment: You wrote errors in your code. Check this out: https://eval.in/630613

Comment: @RichardMauritz  check these  links for further assessment (your initial array in which indexes over-writes previous values)https://eval.in/630605   and output after changing your initial array indexes:-https://eval.in/630585

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I get it now what u mean by all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is a very poor answer but it appears you want UNIQUE data,  here's some very bad code to solve this.

```
$array2 = array();
foreach ($array as $val) 
{
  @$array2[$val['color']]++;
}
foreach ($array as $key=>$val) 
{
  if ($array2[$val['color']] >1)
   unset($array[$key]);
}
```

The `@` is there to prevent php from throwing an error. or you can write more code to predefine `$array2` but this does work.

Comment: why not just type it ^_^, its just one line to initialize

Comment: you can do it on 1 line?  I have to create a 3rd foreach loop for it to be right.

Comment: Thanks, this did exacly what i wanted. Just curious, is there also a one line solution?

Comment: @Forbs  his input array keys are identical. i don't think it's correct

Answer (score 1):

You could get the count of colors first, so that you could distinguish which will be removed and will be kept.

Then, after that, you'll know which color to keep.

To get the count just use `array_count_values` to get which to keep. Then finally, filter:

```
$a = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'color'));
$new_array = array_filter($array, function($e) use($a) {
    return $a[$e['color']] === 1; // filter count equal to 1
});
```

This uses `array_column` which may not be available on your environment, you may use this line as an alternative:

```
$a = array_count_values(array_map(function($e){ return $e['color']; }, $array));
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser. However, the accepted awnser worked like a charm for me ;)

Comment: @RichardMauritz sure no prob

Answer (score 0):

**Assume your array is this**

```
$array = array(
    '0' => array(
        'color' => 'red',
        'type' => 'color',
        'name' => 'color1'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'color' => 'gray',
        'type' => 'color',
        'name' => 'color2'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'color' => 'blue',
        'type' => 'color',
        'name' => 'color3'
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'color' => 'green',
        'type' => 'color',
        'name' => 'color4'
    ),
    '4' => array(
        'color' => 'black',
        'type' => 'color',
        'name' => 'color5'
    ),
    '5' => array(
        'color' => 'gray',
        'type' => 'color',
        'name' => 'color2'
    ),
    '6' => array(
        'color' => 'blue',
        'type' => 'color',
        'name' => 'color3'
    )
);
```

**Code**

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
echo ' <pre>';
print_r($input);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => red
            [type] => color
            [name] => color1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [color] => gray
            [type] => color
            [name] => color2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [color] => blue
            [type] => color
            [name] => color3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [color] => green
            [type] => color
            [name] => color4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [color] => black
            [type] => color
            [name] => color5
        )

)
```

Comment: the OP wants to take out (don't include) array values that has duplicates, check out the expected out, and the first answer is already correct