# What is the best way to index my pages into MySQL database, for a custom PHP search engine?

Tags: php, mysql

I've made this before, but I've forgotten all of the steps.  I've figured how to grab the page using the file_get_contents() function and stripped out all of the unnecessary

```
$data = file_get_contents("index.php"); //read the file
$data = strip_tags($data);
$data = strtoupper($data);
```

Next, I'm using a custom explode function which removes all of the specified separates

```
$sep = "   ():.,!@#$%^&*[]{}?<>;";
$convert = superExplode($data, $sep);
function superExplode($str, $sep) {
    $i = 0;
    $arr[$i++] = strtok($str, $sep);
    while($token = strtok($sep))
    $arr[$i++] = $token;
    return $arr;
}
```

And finally, I count each instance of each word using array_count_values() which stores each word as a key and word count as the value

```
$count = array_count_values($convert);
```

Now I can simply use a foreach loop to get the key and the word count to store in the database.  However, the problem I'm having is that, I'm getting blank keys in the $count array when I do a print_r($count).  So for example:

```
print_r($count);
```

returns:

```
 Array ([] => 1
 [] => 2 
 [] => 1 
 [HOME] => 1 
 [] => 1 
 [SUBMIT] => 1 
 [NEW] => 1 
 [VIEW] => 1)
```

How can I filter out the keys that have nothing in them?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace white spaces with a regular expression. I believe this would work...

`$newData = preg_replace("/\s/", '', $data);`

Comment: chuckieDub, that is meshing all of the words together, but it did remove the white space.  Still not what I need however.

Comment: Ah i see. You an loop through the elements of your array and delete them as in this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php

Comment: chuckieDub, thanks that does seem to be the best approach, however it's not recognizing the blank spaces as null nor " " just a blank space.

Comment: chuckieDub, thanks for your help.  I did figure out the preg_replace it was '$data= preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $data);' instead

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with no arguments to remove empty elements.

```
$convert = array_filter($convert);
$count = array_count_values($convert);
```

Comment: Xeoncross, I just tried that, and it is not filtering out those blank keys. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Erica, I just realized that what you posed isn't possible (array_filter is still the correct way to filter empty elements but not *keys*). You have an error in your output since array's can only contain a *single* key of the same value. You can't have multiple array keys that are blank. Check your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the unset function in the foreach.

```
$array = array(
        '' => '1',
        '' => '2',
        '' => '1',
        'HOME' => '1',
        '' => '1',
        'SUBMIT' => '1',
        'NEW' => '1',
        'VIEW' => '1'
    );

function cleanArray($array){        
    foreach($array as $cleanMe => $value){
        if(empty($cleanMe)){
            unset($array[$cleanMe]);
        }
    }       
    return $array;
}
```

to test it

```
$arr = cleanArray($array);
print_r($arr);
```