# PHP - remove index with duplicated values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, key-value

I have an 2D array, it is simple as this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 6
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 11
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 6
    )
```

Of course, they are inside of another array. What I want is to remove index[2] because it has same values as index[0]. I searched here and on google but couldn't find how to solve issue exactly like this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-php (unsetting an element in a php array)

Comment: Did you search the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)?

Comment: Yes, but that will remove only value, I want to remove complete index.

Comment: @fvu In your case, first I must find duplicates and then unset them. I  think there is a function that does both at the same time  and I have used it but can't remember right now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) with `SORT_REGULAR` flag.

```
array_unique($your_array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: @zavg: you should use SORT_REGULAR, otherwise it performs conversion of inner arrays always producing 'Array'.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka I think that NOTE might come from times before sort_flags added. I really don't see a reason why it should not work now if you can do array(1,2,3) === array(1,2,3).

Comment: @clime Ok, agree, it works cause I tested it on 2 elements array.

Comment: will try it right away - it works..I have misunderstood the function. Thank you @clime

Answer (score 0):

don't crare too much on performance.

```
$dict = array();
foreach($your_data as $one_index){
  $dict[join('',$one_index)]=$one_index;
}

$res=array();
foreach($dict as $one_index){
   $res[] = $one_index;
}

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: can you explain why is there another array? to comapre values or?

Comment: Which one? $dict is to create a hash of the values. which allows for easy comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest having a hash sum calculated for every sub-array in case you have many sub-arrays with many values. Then store that hash into a new array or as an element of the sub-array. Then itterate through comparing hashes and unset($foundArray); for matches.

Comment: Array has no more than 25 'main' indexes, and I know there is a simple way (I did it before) but just can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function array_unique_recusive($arr){
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
if(gettype($value)=='array')
    $arr[$key]=array_unique_recusive($value);
return array_unique($arr,SORT_REGULAR);
}
```

as mentioned here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: 1. what does 'gettype' do?
2. will my original array be owerwritten?

Comment: Well gettype will... get type of the value variable. You can store the return array of the function in a variable. $myArray=array_unique_recusive($originalArray);

Comment: that was obviously :).how to access than that variable in another loop?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. There is already a loop in this function.

Comment: got confused a little bit, it was 03:00AM at my place (now is 07:05 :)).