# I don't understand this array usage

Tags: php, arrays, symfony-1.4

First of all, I apologise for the title, I didn't found a good one for this problem.

I'm working on a Symfony project which already exists and I need to add something. So I'm reading it and I came to a point where arrays are used and I don't understand how it works.

```
$this->categories = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Category c')
            ->leftJoin('c.Sizings s')
            ->where('c.level = 0')
            ->orderBy('c.id ASC, s.gender ASC, s.size ASC')
            ->execute();

        $rCategories = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Category c');
        $allCategories = $rCategories->execute();

        $cat = array();
        foreach($allCategories as $c) {
              [...]
              $cat[$c->getRootId()]['children'][$c->getId()]['root'] = $c;
              [...]
```

So I made some test to see how to access values and this :

```
$cat[$c->getRootId()]['children'][$c->getId()]['root'] = $c;
    foreach($cat as $ca){
      print($ca['root']);
      echo '<br/>';
      foreach($ca['children'] as $child){
        print($child['root']);
      }
    }
die;
```

displays :

```
Tennis Racket //This is the main category
Thunder       //And this is a subcategory
```

First of all, why isn't it IDs instead of Names?

What does this code means exactly?

```
$cat[$c->getRootId()]['children'][$c->getId()]['root'] = $c;
```

At the end there is this :

```
$this->allCategories = $cat;
```

I will use `$allCategories` in a partial in order to display each categories and its subcategories and then include it in my indexSuccess.

But here is the final point, I have to had a new column. The column is already in the DB and I can access its value in the actionclass with

```
$c->getBrand();
```

I would like to had it in the array cat and then in `$this->allCategories` so I can access it in the partial which I use in the indexSuccess and finally set values in the column brand that I had had in the partial.

I'm afraid that I'm not clear enough but in a nutshell :
I don't understand this line :

```
$cat[$c->getRootId()]['children'][$c->getId()]['root'] = $c;
```

And I would like to had a new parameter in the array $cat and access this new value after giving it to indexsuccess through

```
$this->allCategories = $cat;
```

And I want to know how to access the new value.

I hope I'm  clear enough,
Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: I propose you `var_dump` or `print_r` the `$cat` variable to see its structure. This might help analysing the code.

Comment: Would you understand `$cat['foo']['children']['bar']['root'] = $c;`? Or are multi-dimensional associative arrays a mystery to you overall?

Comment: var_dump or print_r gives way too much lines..

@deceze Nope, it's this that I don't understand. I don't know a lot about multi-dimensional arrays. But the only thing I want is to had a third value to $cat which is $c->getBrand()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array parts access](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16467994/476). Read that for an introduction to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you don't include any code for `$c`, it's hard to understand what it actually contains. But in a nutshell, `$c` is an instance of some sort of class.

Most probably it came into existence this way:

```
$c = new someSortOfClass;
```

If you checked out the code for `someSortOfClass`, you'd find `getRootId()` and `getId()` as methods inside it's definition. What they do, is up to the code, and since there is no code to look up to - I assume they return some sort of value that can be a `key` or `index` to an `array`.

What happens next - new elements are created inside a *multi-dimensional* array and the whole instance `$c` is assigned to the 4th level `'root'` array key:

```
$cat[$c->getRootId()]['children'][$c->getId()]['root'] = $c;
```

If you made a `var_dump($cat)`, you would see the entire tree for this array and could then appreciate how it's multi-dimensionality works.

In essence - php arrays can have any sort of value, that include other arrays, so this:

```
$array = Array('key1': 'string', 'key2': Array('child_key1': 2));
print $array['key2']['child_key1']; // 2
```

Is an example of such an array.

Comment: I just edited my post and included the code which leads to the var $c.

Comment: Indeed, `getRootId` and `getRoot` are in the Category class. Symfony creates all `get[column]` for each column in each tables of the database. Here it creates all `get` for each columns of the table Category. So `getRootId` returns the value of the column "rootId" which is an `int`
That's why I don't understand why it displays the string related to the ID and not the ID itself.

Comment: So what I guess `Doctrine_Query` does is abstract a database connection. In that case, whatever it returns - is **always** a string. You have to do type conversion on the returned values yourself. @MrPanda