# Unsetting values in a foreach loop not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array `$allowedViewLevels` with the following example elements:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
)
```

I want to loop trough this array and check if the values are equal to 1, 8 or 11. If so, the corresponding elements should be deleted from the array.

For that, I used the following script:

```
foreach ($allowedViewLevels as $key) {
    if($key==1 || $key==8 || $key==11){
        unset($allowedViewLevels[$key]);
    } 
};

$niveis=implode(",", $allowedViewLevels);
print $niveis;
```

Which is returning:

```
1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11
```

So the elements in the array containing the values 1, 8 or 11 are not being unset from it. What can be wrong with this script?

Comment: You say you want to test the values, but the code tests the keys. Which do you really want to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself (with the help of [this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array/369761#369761).)

It works with the following:

```
$allowedViewLevels=array_diff($allowedViewLevels, array(1,8,11));
$niveis=implode(",", $allowedViewLevels);
print $niveis;
```

Answer (score 1):

An array contains pairs of `[key] => value`.

In your `foreach` loop, you should refer to it that way:

```
foreach ($allowedViewLevels as $key=>$value) {
    if ($value == 1 || $value == 8 || $value == 11) {
        unset($allowedViewLevels[$key]);
    }
} // Also: no semicolon here...

$niveis = implode(",", $allowedViewLevels);
echo $niveis;
```

But, as you've already found the answer yourself, kudos!