# how to delete an array which contains a specified string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called "**VALUES**" that contains multiple arrays. In these array there is a field named "test", I only want the arrays pointed out that contains the number 4 in the test field.

my current output for **Values** array:

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41149 [o_number] => 000001 [test1] => 000001 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Mail [beta] => 30 [test] => 4 ) 

[1] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41142 [o_number] => 000202[test1] => 000202 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Mail [beta] => 30 [test] => 4 ) 

[2] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41103 [o_number] => 000003 [test1] => 000003 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Mail [beta] => 30 [test] => 4 ) 

[3] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41101 [o_number] => 000044 [test1] => 000044 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Manuel/brev [beta] => 10 [test] => 2 ) 

[4] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41100 [o_number] => 000542 [test1] => 000542 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Mail [beta] => 30 [test] => 4 ) 

[5] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41088 [o_number] => 001231 [test1] => 001231 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Mail [beta] => 30 [test] => 3 ))
```

desired output:

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41149 [o_number] => 000001 [test1] => 000001 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Mail [beta] => 30 [test] => 4 ) 

[1] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41142 [o_number] => 000202[test1] => 000202 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Mail [beta] => 30 [test] => 4 ) 

[2] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41103 [o_number] => 000003 [test1] => 000003 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Mail [beta] => 30 [test] => 4 ) 

[3] => Array ( [entry_id] => 41100 [o_number] => 000542 [test1] => 000542 [test2] => 1234 [lev] => Ja [fak] => Mail [beta] => 30 [test] => 4 ))
```

I tried with a foreach but it didn't work

```
    foreach ($values as $key) 
    {
        if($key === 4)
        {
//This will only show
    print_r($key);

//delete array?

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following codes:

```
foreach ($values as $key => &$value) 
{
   if($value['test'] != "4")
      unset($values[$key]);
}

var_dump($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure what you meant, but if you want to iterate over an array in another array try

```
foreach($values as $key => $innerArray) {
    if($innerArray['test'] === 4) {
         do_something();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use

```
//simplified:
$values = array( [0]=>array(['test']=>4))

foreach ($values as $key=>&$sub_values) 
    {
        if($sub_values['test'] === 4)
        {
//This will only show
    print_r($sub_values);

        }else{
          //deleting subarray
          unset($sub_values);
        }
    }
```

No?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value)
{
    if(checkArray())
    {
        continue;
    }
    // do other things
}

function checkArray($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) 
    {
        if ($key === 'test' && $value === 4) {
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using multidimensional arrays it is not that easy  to check whether or not any array consists of that key, without traversing through it. In order to traverse, you can use `foreach`

```
foreach($values as $array) {
    //Now here you can check if the there is `test` index available or is of value `4`

    if(isset($array['test'])) && $array['test'] == '4') {
        //Only then output it
        var_dump($array);
    }
}
```

It is that simple.