# PHP - Remove first result in array

Tags: php, csv

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I have a function that imports a CSV into an array, but i need to remove the first line with the

My CSV is formatted like so:

```
lat,lng,id
-34.837834,1387457,2
```

and so on, you get the ID

My function looks like this

```
private function getArrayFromCsv($file,$delimiter)
{ 

    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 

        $i = 0; 
        while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) { 

            for ($j=0; $j<count($lineArray); $j++) { 

                $dataArray[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j]; 

            } 

            $i++; 

        } 

        fclose($handle); 

    } 

    return $dataArray; 

}
```

The array that is outputted is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => lat
            [1] => lng
            [2] => id
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -34.837834
            [1] => 1387457
            [2] => 2
```

and so on .....

How do i go about removing the array that shows the lat,lng,id and start from the next line in the CSV?

Cheers,

Comment: You use unset.  This question has been answered in detail at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove an element from an array,
    unset($dataArray[0]);
Note that the other element indexes are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), this will reset the indexes on the array as well, while `unset` does not.

```
$unsetTest = array('hey','now','brown','cow');
$shiftTest = array('hey','now','brown','cow');

unset($unsetTest[0]);
array_shift($shiftTest);

var_dump($unsetTest);
var_dump($shiftTest);

//output

array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "now"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "brown"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "cow"
}

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "now"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "brown"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "cow"
}
```

Comment: This should be the ticket answer