# How to remove particular index from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array [0,1,2,3,4] if i got ApplicationStatus = 868 at first then it return only that value other are remove from array. My actual array and i want expected array as below.
Actual Array -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => DENNIS VICENCIO BLANCO
            [ApplicationStatus] => 826
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ARPITA RANJAN DUTTA
            [ApplicationStatus] => 826
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => MARLUNA LIM URUBIO
            [ApplicationStatus] => 868
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => BREDJET - ALEXANDER
            [ApplicationStatus] => 868
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Name] => DENNIS VICENCIO BLANCO
            [ApplicationStatus] => 826
        )

)

Expected Array -
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => DENNIS VICENCIO BLANCO
            [ApplicationStatus] => 826
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => ARPITA RANJAN DUTTA
            [ApplicationStatus] => 826
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => MARLUNA LIM URUBIO
            [ApplicationStatus] => 868
        )    
)
```

So,how to remove remaining key from array.please suggest mi appropriate solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array - not voting to as this would golden-hammer the question.

Comment: No i want to travers upto that ApplicationStatus =868,after that unset all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function:

```
$desired_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($my_array); $i++)
{
    if($my_array[$i]["ApplicationStatus"] == 868)
    {
        $desired_array = array_slice($my_array, 0, $i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear, but you can delete a value from an array with [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function.
For example:

```
unset($arr[3]); // removes array with key = 3
```

...but I would use the [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and would create a function to select the right elements what I need.