# PHP remove element from array issue

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am doing with Laravel 5. And the problem I am facing is that I have an array in session and now I want to remove a single element from that array and for the sake I am using `array_diff` function.

When I get array from session it's in the form like:

```
["4","5","6"]
```

But when I try to remove element '5' from array it deforms the array and the result then is:

```
{"0":"4","2":"6"}
```

My code is:

```
array_diff($arr, array(5))
```

The result is same with `unset([$index])` also.

The real code:

```
Session::push('compare.products', $id); 
$compare = Session::get('compare'); 
if(($key = array_search($id, $compare['products'])) !== false) {   
    unset($compare['products'][$key]);
    return $compare['products']; 
}
```

Comment: When you use: unset($index[1]); it return {"0":"4","2":"6"}??

Comment: Cannot reproduce, you need to post your exact code / a working example: http://ideone.com/ZG6pCi

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: @Katherina Yes the same with unset

Comment: Strange, could you post code ?

Comment: Output should be ["4","6"]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php read that. Array diff is used as the method name says: to calculate the DIFFerence between 2 arrays.

Comment: Session::push('compare.products', $id);
$compare = Session::get('compare');
if(($key = array_search($id, $compare['products'])) !== false) {
                    unset($compare['products'][$key]);
                    return $compare['products'];
                }

Comment: The result is fine to be honest but it's json, it states index 0= 4, index 2= 6

Comment: I posted your code comment as an edit to the question. I assume its the real code you are using

Comment: @MikeM. Except it has converted it to a JSON Object. I dont think the questioner is telling us the complete facts here.

Comment: It's neither unset([$index]); it is: unset($arrayVAR[Index_here]);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep correct indexes you have to call [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) after the unset.

In your case, it will be :

```
Session::push('compare.products', $id); 
$compare = Session::get('compare'); 
if(($key = array_search($id, $compare['products'])) !== false) {   
    unset($compare['products'][$key]);
    return array_values($compare['products']); 
}
```

In a general case, it's :

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3);

unset($array[2]);

$array = array_values($array);
var_dump($array);
/* array(3) {
  [0]=>
     int(0)
  [1]=>
     int(1)
  [2]=>
     int(3)
} */
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/369761/4682796

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question?

Comment: `{"0":"4","2":"6"}` seems to be a kind of var_dump like `["0"=>"4","2"=>"6"]`. And when he says _it deforms the array_ I was thinking that my answer solves the issue with a correct indexed array

Comment: I didn't noticed that it was a JSON output... I was too much focus on PHP directly... Thk ^^