# How to unset/remove an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Okay, I have an array that is created dependant on what data I receive back from a cURL request. I use a regex expression to grab the data I want and then place it into an array. However the data that is returned differs on every request. The problem I am facing now is in the example below. I seem the have two arrays. One containing 2 strings - which is fine. But they other is a blank/empty array.

Current structure:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1196) "
Please select your address from the list below.
Address 1
Address 2
Address 3
Address 4
Address 5
Address 6
" [1]=> string(1196) "
Different Address 1
Different Address 2
Different Address 3
Different Address 4
Different Address 5
Different Address 6
" } array(0) { }
```

My question is how would I go around removing/unsetting `array(0) { }`?

Comment: It appears that the additional, empty array is a separate, non-child of your first `array(2)`. Is that the case, or is it a typo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete an element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Comment: `if(empty($array)){unset($array)}`. why because it is not looking an child array, it is looking a separate array. or if you accidentally put that in a wrong way?

Comment: No, it isn't a typo... unfortunately

Comment: can you try this unset($array[2][0]);

Comment: Which function did you use to generate that layout? Would you please display it via `var_dump` or `print_r`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the php unset function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

```
unset($yourArrayName[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `unset($arrayName[2][0]);`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't seem to target `array(0) { }`