# Tackle specific Array Key

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not a PHP expert or even intermediate by any means.

I am trying to assign a couple of HTML spans to a post title in a WordPress page.php

One span will be added to the first word of the title and the other span should apply to the rest of the rest of the title. 
I started with this code, which got me half way there:

```
<?php
    $words = explode(' ', the_title('', '',  false));
    $words[0] = '<span class="bold-caption">'.$words[0].'</span>';
    $title = implode(' ', $words);
    echo $title;
?>
```

As you can see the first Key of the array has the first spam assigned.

I can't manage to assign the other  to the rest of the title.

How can I accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close...I'd [`unset()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array) the first item after adding a `span` around it, `implode()` the rest, and concatenate:

```
<?php
    // Split the title into an array of words
    $words = explode(' ', get_the_title());
    // Create a new title, with the first word bolded
    $newtitle = '<span class="bold-caption">' . $words[0] . '</span>';
    // Remove the first word from the array of title words
    unset($words[0]);
    // Concatenate the remaining words (in a new span) to the first word
    $newtitle .= '<span>' . implode(' ', $words) . '</span>';

    echo $newtitle;
?>
```