# How do i remove this from an array()?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

How can i remove "dato" from $this->v ? And still have it in the $sql string.

**OUTPUT (var_dump($this->v)):**

```
array (size=4)
  ':kategori' => string 'Youstube' (length=8)
  ':link' => string 'http://urls' (length=11)
  ':navn' => string 'Rss feeds' (length=9)
  ':dato' => string 'NOW()' (length=5)
```

**OUTPUT (echo $sql)**

UPDATE rss_kategori SET kategori = :kategori, link = :link, navn = :navn, dato = NOW()

**CODE:**

```
$classVars = get_class_vars(get_class($this));
            $sql .= "UPDATE {$this->table} SET ";
            foreach ($classVars as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == 'v' || $key == 'db' || $key == 'id' || $key == 'table' || $key ==
                    'table_id') {
                    continue;
                }
                $keys = "";
                $values = "";
                $keys .= $key;
                if ($this->$key == 'NOW()') {
                    $values .= $this->$key . ",";
                } else {
                    $values .= ":" . $key . ",";
                }
                $this->v[":" . $key] = $this->$key;
                $sql .= "{$keys} = " . $values . " ";

            }

            $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2) . " WHERE {$this->table_id} = '{$this->id}'";
```

Comment: you can use `unset`. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$key = ':dato';
$arr = $this->v;
if (array_key_exists($key, $this->v) {
     unset($arr[$key]);
     $this->v = $arr;
}
```

Comment: Can I check if the value NOW() exists in array?

Comment: Yes @nodde. 

    `if (in_array('NOW()', $this->v)) {
        echo "exists";
    } else {
    // Blah blah
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `unset()` function.

```
unset($this->v['dato']);
```