# Remove first element from simple array in loop

Tags: php, arrays

This question has been asked a thousand times, but each question I find talks about associative arrays where one can delete (unset) an item by using they key as an identifier. But how do you do this if you have a simple array, and no key-value pairs?

Input code

```
$bananas = array('big_banana', 'small_banana', 'ripe_banana', 'yellow_banana', 'green_banana', 'brown_banana', 'peeled_banana');

foreach ($bananas as $banana) {
    // do stuff
    // remove current item
}
```

In Perl I would work with `for` and indices instead, but I am not sure that's the (safest?) way to go - even though from what I hear PHP is less strict in these things.

Note that after foreach has run, I expected `var_dump($bananas)` to return an empty array (or null, but preferably an empty array).

Comment: `array_shift` is the best option here.

Comment: @FrayneKonok But doesn't `array_shift` re-index the whole array? Isn't that a problem when you're looping?

Comment: do you need to re-index???

Comment: All arrays have indexes, only because you don't write them explicit doesn't mean the array doesn't have them. So here you just have a 0-based indexed array.

Comment: @FrayneKonok No I don't, but from what I [read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) slicing will re-index the array, and I am wondering if the array is reindexed on the first iteration, won't the second iteration start on `ripe_banana` instead of `small_banana`?

Comment: @Rizier123 I am aware of that, but if an array is re-indexed, doesn't that result in inconsistencies? **Iteration 1** on `big_banana`, ends with shifting that item and *re-indexing*, so `small_banana` becomes 0. But in **iteration 2** the loop might go searching for an index 1 (because 0 has already been done), but index 1 is now `ripe_banana` and not the expected `small_banana`.

Comment: Just unset it, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/369602/3933332

Comment: I'm not an expert on PHP internals but the C source code for `array_shift` says `re-index like it did before`: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6499162ff0d8aa6e862d3e3cdd2288b87636b8a1/ext/standard/array.c#L2708

Comment: why you need to unset the value in the foreach loop????

Comment: @BramVanroy, you have to say something, All we are waiting for your comment. What you really want??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st method (delete by value comparison):

```
$bananas = array('big_banana', 'small_banana', 'ripe_banana', 'yellow_banana', 'green_banana', 'brown_banana', 'peeled_banana');

foreach ($bananas as $key=>$banana) {
    if($banana=='big_banana')
        unset($bananas[$key]);
}
```

2nd method (delete by key):

```
$bananas = array('big_banana', 'small_banana', 'ripe_banana', 'yellow_banana', 'green_banana', 'brown_banana', 'peeled_banana');
unset($bananas[0]);    //removes the first value
unset($bananas[count($bananas)-1]);    //removes the last value
//unset($bananas[n-1]);    removes the nth value
```

Finally if you want to reset the keys after deletion process:

```
$bananas = array_map('array_values', $bananas);
```

If you want to empty the array completely:

```
unset($bananas);
$bananas= array();
```

Answer (score 0):

it still has the indexes

```
 foreach ($bananas as $key => $banana) {
        // do stuff
        unset($bananas[$key]);
    }
```

Comment: it will unset the whole array.

Comment: is it not what he wants?
foreach(..) { //remove current item }

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($bananas); $i++)
{
    //doStuff
    unset($bananas[$i]);
}
```

This will delete every element after its use so you will eventually end up with an empty array.

If for some reason you need to reindex after deleting you can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

How about a `while` loop with `array_shift`?

```
while (($item = array_shift($bananas)) !== null)
{
    // 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Your Note:** Note that after foreach has run, I expected var_dump($bananas) to return an empty array (or null, but preferably
>   an empty array).

Simply use `unset`.

```
foreach ($bananas as $banana) {
    // do stuff
    // remove current item
    unset($bananas[$key]);
}


print_r($bananas);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I will post my idea using [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) for new visitors.

```
while(!empty($bananas)) {
    // ... do something with $bananas[0] like
    echo $bananas[0].'<br>';
    $bananas = array_slice($bananas, 1);
}
```