# if condition fails while checking json array values

Tags: php, json, if-statement

i have a simple json array. in which i have two objects. now i am checking it for some specific values , if found do some thing , if not found do another thing. But i dont know why if condition runs both blocks. **true and false both blocks are executed.** please help.

```
$jsonstring = '{"like":[{"username":"abc","password":"abc"},{"username":"def","password":"def"}]}';
$jsonarr = json_decode($jsonstring);
$count = count($jsonarr->like);
for ($r = 0; $r < $count; $r++) 
{
    if ($jsonarr->like[$r]->username == 'abc' && $jsonarr->like[$r]->password == 'abc') 
    { 
         echo 'Match';
    }else
    {
        echo 'No Match';
    }
}
```

**is it not like regular if condition ?**

Comment: `if (($jsonarr->like[$r]->username == 'abc') && ($jsonarr->like[$r]->password == 'abc'))`
Possible this thing.

Comment: Both blocks are executed during the same loop through or just over the entire loop cycle?

Comment: you are doing this in loop so

Comment: noo.. it giving the same result.. :(

Comment: You have two inputs, and you are supposed to echo two lines. Are you saying 4 lines are being echoed?

Comment: i dont know how is this going ,,  when it founds nothing no match then it displays "no match" twice , i think because there are two objects. so, 2 iteration. but when when it finds matching record ,, it displays first "No match" the "Match". i dont know whats going on there. mysterious loop !!!

Comment: just check please ... i will just take your 2 minutes time .. :)

Comment: main problem is ,, when there is matching record ,, it displays "no match" and  then also "match".

Comment: Suraj, I ran your code on both phpfiddle and my own local php server, and the outcome was as is expected "match" then "no match". see my answer below, should help you, as it shows more detail in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's showing both blocks because you are looping thru the json array which contains two items.  One matching your condition, the other not matching.  Here is a simpler version that does not use a loop but just tests your value if in the array. Notice the 'true' flag in the json_decode as well.

```
<?php

$jsonstring = '{"like":[{"username":"abc","password":"abc"},{"username":"def","password":"def"}]}';
$jsonarr = json_decode($jsonstring, true);

$testArray = $jsonarr['like'];
$loginArray = array('username'=>'abc','password'=>'abc');

if (in_array($loginArray,$testArray)) {
    echo 'match found, do login';
} else {
    echo "no match, do something else";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're too quick for me. ^This is my thought as well.

Comment: ok.. i got that ,, i was thinking this is checking like login system... if record found in array do login otherwise login failed.. something like this. but it is totally doing another way.. how can i check a record exist or not in a json array ?

Comment: Suraj, The loop you're using will work for that.  You just need to put your login methods in the 'match' part of the condition (the 'if'), and do nothing in the 'no match' part of the condition (the 'else'). You honestly don't need the `else` part of your condition here, since it's going to do nothing.  You would just use the `if`.  Then it's going to loop thru your array and run whatever methods are in your 'if' when it finds a match.

Comment: thnxx.. but i just told u about login method as an example.. i simple need --- if record exist do one thing, like call a function & if no match found, call another function. @RobertWade

Comment: OK Suraj, I think I understand what you're after better now.  I modified my answer above with a different piece of code that uses in_array() to test if your login info is actually in that array.

Comment: on the "record found block" can you delete those records from that original array. that is my actual task. i have to delete that position from that array in which i have found that match.

Comment: you would typically use `unset` to handle deleting your array item.  There's a good writeup on how to use that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array