# how to remove an array from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional which is a dynamic array like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => delete
            [label] => hi Delete
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => edit
            [label] => hi Edit
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => update
            [label] => hi update
        )

)
```

now i want to delete an array below from above multidimensional array:

```
Array
    (
        [key] => delete
        [label] => hi Delete
    )
```

finally i want an output like:

Array
    (

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => edit
            [label] => hi Edit
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => update
            [label] => hi update
        )

)
```

For this i have tried, below is my code:

```
<?php
  $arr1 = array(array("key" => "delete", "label" => "hi Delete"),array("key" => "edit", "label" => "hi Edit"), array("key" => "update", "label" => "hi update"));
   $diff = array_diff_assoc($arr1, array("key" => "delete", "label" => "hi Delete"));
   print_r($diff);
?>
```

But i get full $arr1 in the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => delete
            [label] => hi Delete
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => edit
            [label] => hi Edit
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => update
            [label] => hi update
        )

)
```

how can i do this please help me

Comment: You can try unset($arr1[0]);

Comment: here the array is dynamic i don't know the index

Comment: or check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array

Comment: Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php
array_diff is working another way than you expect.

Comment: You are using arrray_diff_assoc($arr1, array("key" => "delete", "label" => "hi Delete")) here $arr1 is multidimension and next one is single dimension that's why you are getting same

Comment: i also try with multidimensional array

Comment: then you have one option left,  loop through array and test for the key upon finding unset that key

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**array_filter**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with `callback` as

```
$arr1 = array_filter($arr1, function ($var) {
    return $var['key'] != 'delete';
});
print_r($arr1);
```

Comment: but the order of index has not  arranged properly, it delete the 0th index and starts array with 1index

Comment: OP mentioned 1,000's of records and seems concerned about performance, using php's array_ functions are much slower than interating through the collection.

Comment: @BunkerBoy then $arr1 = array_values($arr1);

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through the array and test for the key you want to remove, like so: (written blind so youll need to test it!)

```
<?php
foreach ($arr1 as $thisArrIndex=>$subArray)
{
    if ( $subArray['key'] == "delete" )
    {
        unset($arr1[$thisArrIndex]);
    }
}
?>
```

Suggested edit was to break out of the loop after finding the key. It seems OP may have multiple keys like this (in the multiple sub arrays) and so i chose not to break out of the loop here.

Comment: i can not use loop @Stuart , is there any function by which i can do this?

Comment: Why can you not use a foreach...?

Comment: You could loop through 1,000,000 records using foreach in ~0.3 seconds... -- The answer by @Saty is good but performance is **twice as slow as using foreach**....