# How delete array elements from string

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I need to delete a key in an array from a string.

String  is `translations.fr`

Array is

```
[
    ...,
    translations => [
          fr => [
              ...
          ],
          es => [
              ...
          ]
    ],
    ...,
]
```

Result must be :

```
[
    ...,
    translations => [
          es => [
              ...
          ]
    ],
    ...,
]
```

I think, using `exlpode` and `unset` is the good way.

Can you help me ? Thank's

Comment: use the php unset() method for that

Comment: `unset($translation_arr['fr']);` will work.

Comment: try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array

Comment: @NanaPartykar yes but how build key ['fr'] from string ?

Comment: Paste your working code @NicolasLamblin

Comment: Post your solution as answer and accept it; don't post it as addition to the question.

Comment: @deceze it's done, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
public function deleteKeyV3($keyToDelete) {
    $keys = explode('.', $keyToDelete);
    $result = &$array;

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (isset($result[$key])) {
            if ($key == end($keys)) {
                unset($result[$key]);
            } else {
                $result = &$result[$key];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 unset(ArrayName[key][key].....)
```

Comment: Yes but how build key [key][key] from string ?

Comment: $keys = explode('.',"translations.fr") ; $keys[0] = translations; $keys[1] = fr; in this you can get keys

Comment: explode give an array with each key. My problem is to transform this array in $array[$key][$key]

Comment: try this                                                                                                 
$keys = explode('.',"translations.fr") ;
$keys[0] -> translations;
$keys[1] -> fr;
...

unset(${$keys[0]}[$keys[1]]); // ${arrayname}[key]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

If you want to replace the same array and delete the "fr" completely

```
$translationArray = unset($translationArray['fr']);
```

If you want to retain the previous array and save the changes in a new one

```
$translationArrayNew = unset($translationArray['fr']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$str = 'translations.fr';
$exploded = explode('.', $str);
$array = [
        'translations' => [
                'fr' => 'fr value',
                'es' => 'es value',
                ]
        ];

unset($array[$exploded[0]][$exploded[1]]);
```

With `explode` you put your string into an array containing 2 keys: 
0 =>  translations
1 =>  fr

This accesses the 'translations' key within your array

```
$array[$exploded[0]]
```

and this accesses the 'fr' key within 'translations'

```
$array[$exploded[0]][$exploded[1]]
```

it's like writing: `$array['translations]['fr']`